# changing a symbol into a function variable

Tags: functions, matrix

Struggled for a while on this problem and hopefully you can help...  I have a mathematical expression that currently has a symbol where I used to have a function variable.  How do I make the symbol back into a variable, so that my expression becomes a function again?  My function became an expression when I saved it in a matrix, and so now I'm trying to make the different matrix elements back into functions after having constructed the matrix.  Thanks in advance.

> INCLUDING SOME CODE (my first time contributing on this website...)

Imagine a For loop sum (I've removed a substantial amount of code that's irrelevant for now)

```
Pstatesalpha[λ_]=0;
RankMatrix={};
elecdipole (*some vector of numbers delem*)
SumPstatesalpha[λ_, Alpharank_]  (*a predefined function of λ, Alpharank*)

For[Alpharank = 1, Alpharank <= 3, Alpharank++,(
   For[jsum = 1, jsum <=Length[elecdipole], jsum++,(
Pstatesalpha[λ_] = (delem*a0)^2*SumPstatesalpha[λ,Alpharank] + Pstatesalpha[λ];
   )]
AppendTo[RankMatrix, {Alpharank,Pstatesalpha[λ]}]
)]
```

Note that I've saved    Pstatesalpha[λ] 
as a function into     `RankMatrix`.
When I want to access (for instance)

```
RankMatrix[[1,2]]
```

Mathematica returns an expression that includes $\lambda$, but I can't use it as a function anymore.

Comment: This is definitely a job for a substitution rule, but care to give us more info about the said expression?

Comment: By the way, thank you @Spawn1701D and Mr.Wizard for your quick responses.  I should have included an example from the beginning to guide your help better...

Comment: Is `SumPstatesalpha` intended to be a separate function from `Pstatesalpha` or is that a typo?  You say "I can't use it as a function anymore" -- could you give an example how you would like to use it?

Comment: FYI: comments in *Mathematica* are delimited like this: `(* comment *)`

Comment: I added an example to my answer.  Can you confirm that it is what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second try.

In the comments below Spawn's answer you said that you are trying to construct a table of functions.  Does this do what you want?:

```
Pstatesalpha[λ_] = 0;

RankMatrix = {};

For[jsum = 1, jsum <= 3, jsum++,
 Pstatesalpha[λ_] = (delem*a0)^2*SumPstatesalpha[λ] + Pstatesalpha[λ];
 AppendTo[RankMatrix, {Alpharank, Function @@ {λ, Pstatesalpha[λ]}}]
]
```

The key detail is appending `Function @@ {λ, Pstatesalpha[λ]}` which will build a function with the evaluated expression `Pstatesalpha[λ]` as the body and the parameter `λ`.

Now:

```
RankMatrix[[1, 2]][17]
```

> ```
> a0^2 delem^2 SumPstatesalpha[17]
> ```

---

Since the above was Accepted (thanks) let me explain a bit better.

I use the method `fn @@ {args}` to evaluate `args` and pass them to a function `fn` (using `Apply`) that otherwise holds its arguments (has a Hold attribute).

In the code above, copied from the question, there is a global symbol `λ` which if assigned a value will break the code.  One method to avoid this is to use a Formal Symbol, entered <kbd>Esc</kbd>`$x`<kbd>Esc</kbd> where `x` is any a-z letter.  These symbols exist specifically for cases like this.  Another method is to use `Slot` as in the syntax `# + 2 &` (the `FullForm` of `#` is `Slot[1]`).  That might look like this (in context):

```
AppendTo[RankMatrix, {Alpharank, Evaluate[Pstatesalpha[#]] &}]
```

`Evaluate` is used instead of `Apply` and `List`, but many methods are possible:

```
Evaluate[Pstatesalpha[#]] &

Function @@ {Pstatesalpha[#]}

With[{body = Pstatesalpha[#]}, body &]

Pstatesalpha[#] /. x_ :> (x &)
```

With each of these `Pstatesalpha[#]` is evaluated outside of `Function` and then inserted into it.

Comment: You know, I think that did it!  I'd been using `Function` for a good 3+ hours but it never seemed to work correctly.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Verde I'm glad this helped.  `Function` works properly, just not the way that you anticipated.  It is often important that the body of a function not evaluate until the parameters are filled, therefore `Function` has the `HoldAll` attribute. (See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121) for another example where that gets in the way.)  Since `List` does not have `HoldAll`, and is syntactically concise, `fn @@ {args}` is a common method to evaluate `args` and pass them to a function `fn` (using `Apply`) that otherwise holds its arguments.

Comment: @Verde I added a few more details and methods to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if I understand correctly you want to create a list of functions for example

```
RankMatrix={}

For[jsum = 1, jsum <= 3, jsum++,
       Pstatesalpha[jsum][x_] = (delem*a0)^2*SumPstatesalpha[x] + Pstatesalpha[x];
       AppendTo[RankMatrix, {Alpharank,Pstatesalpha[jsum]}]
    ]
```

Now on `RankMatrix` you have a matrix including a set of functions and to access one of them : `RankMatrix[[1,2]][λ]`

In Mathematica we often don't use the procedural methods employed in the usual programming languages, like for, do etc. I give you an equivalent solution using Mathematica's command for matrix creation:

```
RankMatrix= Array[Function[Pstatesalpha[#][x_] = (delem*a0)^2*SumPstatesalpha[x] + 
                  Pstatesalpha[x];{Alpharank, Pstatesalpha[#]}], 
                  3]
```

Comment: Yes - what I intended to create with AppendTo was a matrix of functions.  However, when I ask for a matrix element outside of the For loop, it's not a function anymore, but an expression...

Comment: @Verde  In this way inside the _loop_ you define the function and on the matrix you get its ... Head. I assume that in your specific problem the formula and `Alpharank` changes for different values of `jsum` ...

Comment: I'm going to try to work with your suggestion, but the thing is, there's actually a For loop inside a For loop because of the different variables I have to sum over.  I would rather not get rid of the For loops, to be honest.  What I'm creating with these For loops is a function whose variable is $\lambda$ that I can calculate things with, plot, etc.  I don't have a pre-defined list of values to calculate the function for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Spawn1701D.  I'm going to have to learn how to use your comments in my code.  It'll simplify it, I bet...