# How can I create a list of functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Can anyone tell me, how to create a list of functions? I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
For[i = 0, i < 5, i++,
{
  functionList[[i]][t_]:=(t*i*i)
}]

functionList[[3]][10]
```

Of course, this construction is just an example.

Comment: Something like this? `Through[{f, g, h}[x]]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
functionList = Table[With[{i = i}, #*i*i &], {i, 0, 4}]

functionList[[3]][10]
```

> ```
> {#1 0 0 &, #1 1 1 &, #1 2 2 &, #1 3 3 &, #1 4 4 &}
>
> 40
> ```

The `With` is used to get the values inside `Function`, which has the `HoldAll` attribute, as described in: [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121)

---

The method above is more general and likely easier to read but for completeness here is another method, in this specific case notably more concise:

```
Array[# /. i_ :> (#*i*i &) &, 4]
```

> ```
> {#1 1 1 &, #1 2 2 &, #1 3 3 &, #1 4 4 &}
> ```

Note that there are two different Functions in this code.  The replacement rule is used in an inverted way that I have been calling the "[injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121)," and although destructuring is not used here this is similar in form to what I proposed early in my answer to [Mathematica Destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/mathematica-destructuring/8399#8399).

Answer (score 6):

Here's an even simpler way to create a "list" of functions, just define the function to have two arguments. To follow your example:

```
f[i_, t_] := t i^2
```

So now if you want the 5th function, it's

```
 f[5,t]
```

which gives `25 t`. Or you can evaluate it at any point:

```
f[5,7]
```

to get `175.` If you wanted `f` to behave more like a proper list so as to accept only integer-valued $i$, then you can force this by restricting the domain of $f$. For example:

```
f[i_?IntegerQ, t_] := t i^2
```

This $f$ will remain unevaluated for noninteger $i$.

Comment: Of course, one could also do `f[i_][t_] := t i^2`, which allows for nice constructions like `f[2] /@ Range[5]`.

Comment: Yes... it is kind of hard to tell what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
functionList1 = Table[Evaluate[#*i*i] &, {i, 0, 4}]
functionList2 = Function[x, x^2 # &] /@ Range[0, 4]

functionList1[[3]]@10
functionList2[[3]]@10

(*
{0 &, #1 &, 4 #1 &, 9 #1 &, 16 #1 &}
{0^2 #1 &, 1^2 #1 &, 2^2 #1 &, 3^2 #1 &, 4^2 #1 &}
40
40
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps one of these steps will help.

(1) Create a list of functions you wish to apply:

```
fcnlist = {Sin, Cos, Tan}
```

(2) Now define myfunc using a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) which applies the selected function from fcnlist to an argument x of your choice:

```
myfunc[f_, x_] := fcnlist[[#1]] /@ {#2} &[f, x]
```

(3) To generate a list of results with [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html?q=Table&lang=en):

```
Table[myfunc[i, π/6], {i, 1, 3}]
(* {{1/2}, {Sqrt[3]/2}, {1/Sqrt[3]}} *)
```

If you specifically want the function to be `t i^2`, then you simply generate a list of functions as long as you like:

```
fcnlist = Table[# i^2 &, {i, 1, 5}]
(* {#1 i^2 &, #1 i^2 &, #1 i^2 &, #1 i^2 &, #1 i^2 &} *)
```

When you apply this fcnlist as above with myfunc, you can generate a list of results as long as you wish (in this case 3 results again):

```
Table[myfunc[i, t], {i, 1, 3}]
(* {{t}, {4 t}, {9 t}} *)

Table[myfunc[i, 5], {i, 1, 3}]
(* {{5}, {20}, {45}} *)
```