# How do I generate a list of delayed rules?

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

I want a list like this:

```
{x :> Print[1], x :> Print[2], x :> Print[3], x :> Print[4], x :> Print[5]}
```

I tried:

```
Table[x :> Print[i], {i, 5}]
```

But it gives:

```
{x :> Print[i], x :> Print[i], x :> Print[i], x :> Print[i], x :> Print[i]}
```

It seems that you can't iterate things on the right hand side of delayed rules. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: Related: [(25388)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25388/121)

Answer (score 5):

This question is answered elsewhere, but to get some ink on the page until I can link the duplicate here is a CW answer.

I would use [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Array.html):

```
Array[(x :> Print[#]) &, 5]
```

> ```
> {x :> Print[1], x :> Print[2], x :> Print[3], x :> Print[4], x :> Print[5]}
> ```

Other methods using `Table`:

```
Table[With[{n = i}, x :> Print[n]], {i, 5}]

Table[(x :> Print[n]) /. n -> i, {i, 5}]

Table[i /. n_ :> (x :> Print[n]), {i, 5}]

Table[(x :> Print[#]) &[i], {i, 5}]
```

---

Contrived ways for amusement if nothing else:

```
MapAt[Print, RuleDelayed @@@ Thread[x -> Range[5]], {All, 2}]

Table[Hold[RuleDelayed][x, Hold[Print][i]], {i, 5}] // ReleaseHold

Table[x -> p[i], {i, 5}] /. {p -> Print, Rule -> RuleDelayed}

List @@ Thread[x :> Evaluate[Print /@ Hold @@ Range@5], Hold]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ToExpression@
 Table["x \[RuleDelayed] Print[" <> ToString[i] <> "]", {i, 5}]
```

> {x :> Print[1], x :> Print[2], x :> Print[3], x :> Print[4],   x :>
>   Print[5]}

Comment: Sorry, but this is about the worst way to solve this IMO.  :-(  This question is also a duplicate and I am searching for the original(s).