# Problem of RuleDelayed, how to evaluate some parts of the right side of RuleDelayed

Tags: evaluation, rule

Problem of `RuleDelayed`

```
NameList = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

rules = Table[NameList[[i]] <> "=" ~~ x__ ~~ "\n" :> NameList[[i]] <> 
              "=" ~~ OptionValue["Position"] ~~ "\n", {i, Length@NameList}];
```

output of `rules[[1]]` is

```
a=~~x__~~  :>NameList[[i]]<>=~~OptionValue[Position]~~
```

Here, since I used `RuleDelayed`, `NameList` in the right-hand side is not evaluated.

One workaround is to use Rule, but `Rule` may cause some warning errors concerning not a string.

```
rules = Table[k = i; NameList[[i]] <> "=" ~~ x__ ~~ "\n" -> NameList[[k]] <> "=" ~~ 
              OptionValue["Position"] ~~ "\n", {i, Length@NameList}];

rules[[1]]

(*
    a=~~x__~~->a=~~OptionValue[Position]~~
*)
```

How to solve that in the `RuleDelayed` case? the effect like the `Rule` case?

Answer (score 3):

If your example is representative I would just use this:

```
NameList = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

(# <> "=" ~~ x__ ~~ "\n" :> # <> "=" ~~ OptionValue["Position"] ~~ "\n") & /@ NameList
```

> ```
> {"a=" ~~ x__ ~~ "
>    " :> "a" <> "=" ~~ OptionValue["Position"] ~~ "
>    ", "b=" ~~ x__ ~~ "
>    " :> "b" <> "=" ~~ OptionValue["Position"] ~~ "
>    ", "c=" ~~ x__ ~~ "
>    " :> "c" <> "=" ~~ OptionValue["Position"] ~~ "
>    ", "d=" ~~ x__ ~~ "
>    " :> "d" <> "=" ~~ OptionValue["Position"] ~~ "
>    "}
> ```

If for some reason you must use `Table` see: [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121).  `RuleDelayed` also has a hold attribute, like `Function`, so the cause and solutions are the same.

Comment: +1, much nicer than mine. The "anonymity" of # prevents variable name trouble here. Compare with `Function[yyy, (yyy <> "=" ~~ x__ ~~ "\n" :> 
    yyy <> "=" ~~ OptionValue["Position"] ~~ "\n")] /@ NameList` where `x$__` occurs in the output. Somehow a good refresher for me.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of writing `With` in terms of `ReplaceAll` in order to avoid problems with ugly variable names in scoping constructs, we can write

```
ClearAll[rules]
rules =
  Table[
   ReplaceAll[
    Unevaluated[
     nl <> "=" ~~ x__ ~~ "\n" :> 
      nl <> "=" ~~ OptionValue["Position"] ~~ "\n"
     ],
    HoldPattern@nl -> NameList[[i]]
    ]
   ,
   {i, Length@NameList}
   ]
```

Output

[image]

I suppose one slight difference is that "a"<>"=" did not become "a=", as is the case when you used `Rule`. It would be nicer if the strings were joined, but yeah I think this is fine :).