# Appending functions to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

Could someone please explain the difference between these methods, and possibly a nicer way to get the first result? (This is a toy example and in my real program I'd like to use `Do` rather than `Table` or similar as there are imperative and global things going on).

Method 1 (Desired result):

```
In[5]:= fsum[f_]=Total@Through[f@#]&;
fs={};
Do[
AppendTo[fs,#^n1&/.n1->n];
,{n,0,10}]
fsum[fs][a]

Out[8]= 1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4+a^5+a^6+a^7+a^8+a^9+a^10
```

Method 2:

```
In[9]:= fsum[f_]=Total@Through[f@#]&;
fs={};
Do[
AppendTo[fs,#^n&];
,{n,0,10}]
fsum[fs][a]
Out[12]= 11 a^n
```

Method 3:

```
In[13]:= fsum[f_]=Total@Through[f@#]&;
fs={};
Do[
n1=n;
AppendTo[fs,#^n1&];
,{n,0,10}]
fsum[fs][a]
Out[16]= 11 a^10A
```

Comment: I think this question can be closed as a duplicate of: [(7756)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756) -- please review that question and tell me if you disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use

```
fs = Reap[Do[With[{n = n}, Sow[#^n &]], {n, 0, 10}]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {#1^0 &, #1^1 &, #1^2 &, #1^3 &, #1^4 &, #1^5 &, #1^6 &, #1^7 &, #1^8 &, #1^9 &, #1^10 &}
> ```

Your methods 2 & 3 don't work because `Function` has the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html?q=HoldAll) and therefore

```
m = 2;
#^m &
```

> ```
> #1^m &
> ```

[`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html?q=With) can be used "to insert values into held expressions."