# How do I create palette window with status area?

Tags: front-end, options, palettes

I would like to create a palette with a small empty bar at the bottom that displays text as the user hovers their mouse over various buttons (like at the bottom of the built-in "Basic Type-setting" palette).

I tried setting the option `WindowStatusArea->True` and `Automatic` but the status bar at the bottom doesn't show:

```
CreatePalette[
  PasteButton[
    Style[
      StatusArea["\[Gamma]", "esc-g-esc"], FontFamily -> "Courier", 12],
    RawBoxes["\[Gamma]"], ImageSize -> {30, 20}], 
WindowStatusArea -> True]
```

leads to:
[image]

Which option do I need to set to get the status area bar at the bottom of the palette?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WindowElements -> {"StatusArea"}`

```
CreatePalette[
 PasteButton[  Style[StatusArea["\[Gamma]", "esc-g-esc"], 
                     FontFamily -> "Courier", 12], 
               RawBoxes["\[Gamma]"], ImageSize -> {30, 20}], 
 WindowStatusArea -> ":)", 
 WindowElements -> {"StatusArea"}]
```

[image]

Full answer:

```
CreatePalette[
 Table[With[{i = i},
   Annotation[Button[Row[{"Label ", i}], Print[i]], "Yeah, " <> ToString[i], "Mouse"]
   ],
  {i, 10}],
 WindowStatusArea -> Dynamic[MouseAnnotation[":("]], 
 WindowElements -> {"StatusArea"}]
```

Comment: I don't see anything happening when I hover the mouse over the button; the `:)` icon is always there. (*Mathematica* 10.0.1, OS X.)

Comment: @murray done :p

Comment: @Kuba I hope I am not breaking any rule by asking this here but, could you please explain to me the need of `With[{i=i},...]`? Why is that necessary? What does it do / prevent? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @RoberRM, sure, take a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7758/5478 and let me know if that explanation is not clear.

Comment: @Kuba I understood perfectly. Thank you!