# How to briefly display message in status area?

Tags: front-end

The function `StatusArea` can be used to display stuff in the status area, but only when the user hovers the mouse over the appropriate location.

I want to display a message in the status area *for a few seconds*, and not requiring the user to hover the mouse anywhere for this to happen.

---

Basically, I have a function that restarts the kernel (based on one from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68864/customize-keybindings-without-modifying-files-in-the-installation-directory/68871#68871)); I want it to briefly display a message like "Kernel restarted" in the status area.

Comment: related: [**66773**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66773/5478)

Comment: Also related: [(26438)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26438/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like that?

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowStatusArea] = "whatever"
Pause[1]
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowStatusArea] = Inherited
```

probably something like this will give you more flexibility:

```
With[
    {nb = EvaluationNotebook[]}
  , CurrentValue[nb, WindowStatusArea] = "whatever"
  ; RunScheduledTask[CurrentValue[nb, WindowStatusArea] = Inherited, {1}]
];
```