# How to display the error in interation in a comfortable way?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

For example `t = 0.5; Do[t = Module[{a = t}, c = (a^2 - 2)/3;Pause[1]; err = c - a; c]; 
 Print[err], {i, 100}]` I want to see the `err`in every interation step while the code is running. But I don't want to see the `err` in my code notebook.Is there anyway to show it elsewhere? (in a new notebook or bottom border?)

Comment: Check out the `showStatus` function from  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Messages Window

You can use this `printMsg` function, replacing `Print` in your code:

```
printMsg[x__] := 
 NotebookWrite[
   Notebooks["Messages"][[1]],
   Cell[RawBoxes @ ToBoxes @ Row @ {x}, "Text"]
 ]
```

This should print to the [Messages window](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/Messages.html), which you may need to open.

### Window Status Area

To print to the StatusArea of the evaluation notebook use this in place of `Print`:

```
printStatus[x__] :=
  (CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowStatusArea] = ToString @ Row @ {x};)
```

Reference: [How to briefly display message in status area?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140074/121)

### Monitor

If you only want to see one value rather than a list of values you can use [`Monitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html), though this does display within the Notebook.

```
x = 0;

Monitor[
 Do[x++; Pause[1], {50}],
 x
]
```

See also: [Interrogating a running evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/178784/121)

Comment: Thank you Mr Wizard