# How to substitute inside Hold? How to create table of summation (with Sigma symbol) expressions?

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation, hold

I would like to create table of summation expressions, which are not evaluated, but summation limits are substituted.

I can't accomplish this so far.

If I write

[image]

I get summation expanded.

If I write:

[image]

I get "Hold" word displayed and summation limits not substituted.

If I write:

[image]

I get limits not substituted.

Comment: You have been a member for 2 years and 11 months and you post images instead of actual code ?

Comment: Because visual representation matters here. The code is not very smart anyway.

Comment: Providing code would be a good idea nevertheless.

Comment: Use `With[{n=n},...` to inject into held expressions.

Comment: Closely related: [7756](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478) but I'd even say a duplicate.

Comment: `Inactive` may be of interest here:  `Table[Inactive[Sum][Subscript[a, i, j], {i, m}, {j, n}], {m, 3}, {n, 4}]`.  Otherwise: `Table[HoldForm@Sum@## & @@ {Subscript[a, i, j], {i, m}, {j, n}}, {m, 3}, {n, 4}]`