# Controlling the evaluation of other arguments in pure functions

Tags: functions, evaluation, list-manipulation

I have a piece of code where I would like to do the something like the following:

```
ComposeList[Table[Which[
m < 3, f[#, m] &,
m < 6, f[#, m + 1] &
], {m, 1, 5, 1}], x]
```

The idea here is to repeatedly apply `f` to `x`, but with the second argument of `f` changing in some way as it goes. However, this does not work, because pure functions are left unevaluated. That means that the `m` in `f[#,m]` stays as `m` when the table is created, which is then meaningless later on.

If I try and fix this by wrapping `f[#,m]` in `Evaluate`, it evaluates not only `m`, but also `f`. This is a problem for me, because it tries to evaluate `f` with that `Slot` still in the first argument, and `f` is very complicated and it fails. I really need the resulting table to look like `{f[#,1], f[#,2],...}`.

The only solution I came up with is as follows:

```
ComposeList[Table[Which[
m < 3, f @@@ Function[Evaluate[qpzrqrq[#, m]]],
m < 6,  f @@@ Function[Evaluate[qpzrqrq[#, m + 1]]]
], {m, 1, 5, 1}], x]
```

Here I am evaluating the pure function with a different head (`qpzrqrq`) which I hope is not actually defined anywhere. This evaluates the arguments, and then I replaced `qpzrqrq` with the actual function `f`. However, this is definitely a hack, and relies on `qpzrqrq` being undefined. Does anyone have a better solution to this problem?

Comment: It seems to me that [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) should be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html?q=With)

```
ComposeList[
 Table[
  With[{m = m}, Which[m < 3, f[#, m] &, m < 6, f[#, m + 1] &]],
  {m, 1, 5, 1}],
 x]
```

> ```
> {x, f[x, 1], f[f[x, 1], 2], f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], f[f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], 5], 
>  f[f[f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], 5], 6]}
> ```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This question is probably a duplicate of: [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121)

If not I think you want [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html):

```
FoldList[f, x, Table[If[m < 3, m, m + 1], {m, 5}]]
```

> ```
> {x, f[x, 1], f[f[x, 1], 2], f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], f[f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], 5], 
>  f[f[f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], 5], 6]}
> ```

---

As stated I think this is a duplicate but there may be methods applicable here that are not general.  If `f` will not evaluate incorrectly when passed a literal `#` as an argument you could simply let the nascent `Function` bodies evaluate first, then make functions of them after:

```
ComposeList[
  Function /@ Table[If[m < 3, f[#, m], f[#, m + 1]], {m, 5}],
  x
]
```

You could also use Function itself to inject values:

```
ComposeList[Array[m \[Function] If[m < 3, f[#, m] &, f[#, m + 1] &], 5], x]
```

However if your problem is best solved by `With[{m = m}, . . .` I shall mark this as a duplicate, as it is the Accepted answer to the existing question.

Comment: Iversonian magic: `m + Boole[m >= 3]`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this solution is that my actual application is a little more complicated than the stripped down version I posted. Really the function statement is more like f[#,a,b,g[m],c,d,h[m]]. In other words, there are several arguments, some of which are dependent on the table index m. It's not obvious to me how to use FoldList to implement that. I'm guessing Sequence could be helpful, but I think the command would get pretty ugly.

Comment: @jmizrahi Please see the update, and also tell me if you think this question should *not* be marked as a duplicate and why.

Comment: I think you're right that it is a duplicate. The `With` solution solved my problem nicely. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Evaluate`

```
res1 =
 ComposeList[
  Table[
   Evaluate[Which[
      m < 3, f[#, m],
      m < 6, f[#, m + 1]]] &,
   {m, 5}],
  x]
```

> {x, f[x, 1], f[f[x, 1], 2], f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], f[f[f[f[x, 1], 2],
>   4], 5],   f[f[f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], 5], 6]}

```
res2 =
 ComposeList[
  Table[
   Evaluate[Piecewise[{
       {f[#, m], m < 3},
       {f[#, m + 1], m < 6}}]] &,
   {m, 5}],
  x]
```

> {x, f[x, 1], f[f[x, 1], 2], f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], f[f[f[f[x, 1], 2],
>   4], 5],   f[f[f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 4], 5], 6]}

```
res1 === res2
```

> True