# How to make variable values from evaluation time persist in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, variable

In the context of automatic report generation, I am trying to use a `For` loop to `Print` out a number of `Manipulate` expressions.

I have made a simple example to illustrate the essence of the problem:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
  Print[Manipulate[i, {t, 0, 1}]]
  ];
```

After evaluating this, the following is displayed:

[image: Notebook output]

However, I wish the value of a variable, in this case the momentary value of `i`, to persist in `Manipulate`. In this case, this would result in 1, 2, and 3 being displayed instead of 4, 4, and 4.

So far, I have tried using `Initialization`, `Module`, `ReplaceAll`, and `Unique` for this purpose, and surprisingly, nothing worked.

For example, this code yields the same result as the one above:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
  Print[Manipulate[s, {t, 0, 1}, Initialization :> (s = i)]]
  ];
```

Comment: I can not understand what you are looking for. Since your `Manipulate`'s control `t` is in no way coupled to expression it displays in its content pane, there seems no reason at all to be using `Manipulate`. Can you come up with a better example where the `Manipulate` expression is actually relevant?

Comment: Sure, for example with `s+t` instead of `s` as the first argument in `Manipulate` in the second code (but that would distract from the fact that the value of `s` does not persist in the sense I have described).  I tried to make the example as simple as possible; that's one of the debugging strategies that I was taught and rely on.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Hi, Jake, thanks for taking care about the minimal example. `Manipulate` has a `HoldAll` attribute so this answers apply: [Using pure functions in Table](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478). Does this help?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple scoping problem. Try

```
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++, 
  With[{i = i}, Print[Manipulate[i, {t, 0, 1}]]]];
```

[image: figure]

The funny-looking first argument of the [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) expression, injects the current value of `i` into the `Manipulate` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DynamicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[{i = #}, Manipulate[i, {t, 0, 1}]] & /@ Range[3] // Column
```

Hope this helps.