# How to use OptionValue inside a pure function

Tags: function-construction, pure-function, optional-arguments

I want to define a function with `OptionsPattern` as argument which returns a pure function using `OptionValue`:

```
Options[f] = {"opt" -> value};
f[OptionsPattern[f]] := (# + OptionValue@"opt") &
```

However, I get the unexpected result

```
f[]
```

> ```
> #1 + OptionValue[f, {}, "opt"] &
> ```

instead of

> ```
> (#1 + value) &
> ```

what I would expect.

How can I define a function such that I obtain my expected definition?

Comment: Use `With` to inject it. `Function` is `HoldAll`.

Comment: What Kuba said will work, but using a SubValue definition may (or may not) be a better solution, depending on your application.  `f[...][...] := ...`.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(7756)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121)

Comment: Thanks Kuba Szabolcs @Mr.Wizard using some kind of injector pattern did the trick