# What' s wrong with my code with `play` in table

Tags: sound

I couldn't find the reason why the following code consumming my time (1min no output results):

```
lis = {1, 3, 7, 19};
Sound[Table[
 Play[Sum[4/(Pi j) Sin[440*j*(t + Pi/2/440)], {j, 1, i, 2}], {t, 0, 
   0.7 2 Pi/440}],
 {i, lis}
 ]
]
```

Comment: `Play` is `HoldAll` so you need to add `Table[With[{i = i},...`, otherwies MMA chokes with "symbolic" `Play`.

Comment: As Kuba said, or use `Play[Sum[4/(Pi j) Sin[440*j*(t + Pi/2/440)], {j, 1, #, 2}], {t, 0, 
     0.7 2 Pi/440}] & /@ lis // Sound`

Comment: See the many linked/duplicate questions for more examples: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7756?lq=1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard good enough? [7756](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478). I feel that a generic topic about Hold* attributes and Block based iterators would be very useful. That's a FAQ.

Comment: Why are they Block based and there is no built in With based alternative is another question.

Comment: @Kuba Do you feel that 7756 is not sufficiently generic?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
lis = {1, 3, 7, 19};
Sound[Play[
           Sum[4/(Pi j) Sin[440*j*(t + Pi/2/440)], {j, 1, #, 2}],
          {t, 0, 0.7 2 Pi/440}] & /@ lis]
```

[image]