# Input Matrix using Table and InputField

Tags: list-manipulation, inputfield

I'm trying to make a square matrix of `InputField`s, where the size is dependent on what the user chooses.  Each cell should be independent of each other.

Here's what I tried:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
dimension = 3;
inputA = Partition[Table[
           InputField[Dynamic[a[i], Function[If[# =!= Null && IntegerQ[#], a[i] = #]]], 
                      Number, FieldSize -> 4], 
                      {i, dimension^2}], dimension];
```

But when I run this, all of the cells are assigned as one variable, so if I put in a number in any of the cells, the rest of the cells auto-populate to that number. I am lost as to what I'm doing wrong here.  Why doesn't the table assign the cells as `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and so on?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#1689176465

Comment: @wuyingddg thank you!

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478

Answer (score 1):

Following the tutorial pointed to by wuyingddg,

```
dim = 3; a = ConstantArray[0, dim^2]; 
Partition[Table[With[{i = i}, InputField[Dynamic[a[[i]]]]], 
               {i, dim^2}], dim] // TableForm
```