# DumpSave a variable in Do loop

Tags: save

I have the following code:

```
ff={"a","b"}
Do[
    mm[ff[[i]]]=RandomReal[];
,{i,Length@ff}]
Do[
    DumpSave["D:\\"<>ToString@ff[[i]]<>".mx",mm[ff[[i]] ]];
,{i,Length@ff}]
```

This gives

> DumpSave::bsnosym: mm[ff[[i]]] is not defined as a symbol or a
>   context.

So obviously the `mm[ ff[[i]] ]` is not replace as needed when i is set to 1,2,... . The goal is to dump e.g. mm["a"] in a file called a.mx. And this with all the item in the list ff. Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: `DumpSave` is `HoldRest` so see [7756](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478) but are you aware that `DumpSave["test", mm["a"]]` won't work anyway?

Comment: The second argument of DumpSave must be a symbol with assigned definitions. It is these definitions that will be written into a file.  DumpDave cannot export *pure data* without assigning it to a variable first. If you just want to store data, use Export (to MX format) and not DumpSave.

Comment: I see I have to re-think my strategy here. I did not new that Export to MX also works.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked topic will not work since you want to work with parts but the whole topic gives a good overview of available methods.