# Problem with Excel operation in NETLink way

Tags: excel, procedural-programming, .netlink, excellink

I'm using the NETLink package to build a Excel file and trying to fill it with some data as this:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];

(*xls = NETNew["Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass"];*)
xls = CreateCOMObject["Excel.Application"];
xls@Visible = True;

wb = xls@Workbooks@Add[]
ws = wb@Worksheets@Item[1]
```

it works with code :

```
ws@Cells[1, 1]@Value = 100;
ws@Cells[2, 2]@Value = 200;
ws@Cells[3, 3]@Value = 300;
```

but gives no result with code:

```
For[i=1,i<10,i++,
   ws@Cells[i, i]@Value = i*100
]
```

so,what's wrong with the loop case ? Thanks!

```
(*Solution*)
(*define func.*)
wsGetCell[i_,j_]:=ws@Cell[i,j]
(*loop*)
For[i=1,i<10,i++,
       wsGetCell[i, i]@Value = i*100
    ]
```

Comment: NETLink object has to have some upvalues associated to how you can access methods etc. Without this 'environment'  `Cells[1,1]` would just return `$Failed`. Anyway, since `Cells[i,i]` is held during the evaluation those notes apply: [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478).

Comment: Is there any way to release the cells' held evaluations, I've tested the `Activate` function but it doesnot work.

Comment: This doesn't answer the NetLink question, but ExcelLink makes interaction with Excel files easy. I use it literally everyday. Perhaps it has some deficiencies that I haven't encountered yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Excel object model, the worksheet symbol `Cells` represents a property, not a method.  In Visual Basic and other languages, many properties have a default method called `Item`.  NETLink does not fully implement this notion of a default method:

```
ws@Cells[3, 3]@Value

(* 3 *)
```

but:

```
$i = 3;
ws@Cells[$i, $i]@Value

(* (NETLink`Objects`NETObject$1412516038$971395236364289)[$i, $i][Value] *)
```

Notice how the expression remains unevaluated.  But it will work if we use the *Item* method explicitly:

```
ws@Cells@Item[$i, $i]@Value

(* 300 *)
```

`Item` will allow us to perform a successful assignment as well.  So, we can adjust the `For` loop to get the expected behaviour as follows:

```
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++,
   ws@Cells@Item[i, i]@Value = i*100
]
```

**Internal Details**

Part of the problem here is that assignment statements *appear* to work but fail silently:

```
ws@Cells[$i, $i]@Value = 3

(* 3 *)
```

This is due to an NETLink implementation problem.  The code expects the invalid property reference to return `$Failed` but gets confused when, as we have seen, it remains unevaluated.  Working from the top-level expression inward, the relevant evaluation sequence for `ws@Cells[$i, $i]@Value = 3` looks like this (at least as of version 11.3):

[image: evaluation sequence]

For technical reasons, this behaviour might be difficult to correct in the general case.

Comment: Hm, it's strange that ``NETLink`Package`nCall`` doesn't return `$Failed` when its first argument is `$Failed`, which means that the type has not been inferred correctly... It looks like it would solve the problem of the seemingly successful evaluation...

Answer (score 5):

It works with code.

```
Scan[(ws@Cells[#, #]@Value = #*100) &, Range@10]
```

It seems that vars `i` in `ws@Cells[i, i]@Value` be not evaluated immediately when the loop goes. I wonder is it a bug in NETLink package?

Update v1:

```
(ws@Cells[#, #]@Value = #*100) & /@ (Range@10);
```

Update v2 using `Range` to fill values faster

```
content = Table[i*j,{i,1,100},{j,1,100}];
lstVals = {{First@Dimensions@content}}~
   Join~{{Last@Dimensions@content}}~Join~{{content}};
(* to avoid vars evaluating in Excel Cells objects *)
MapThread[(ws@Range[ws@Cells[1, 1], ws@Cells[#1, #2]]@Value = #3) &, 
  lstVals];
```

Comment: +1 `With[{i = 3}, ws@Cells[i, i]@Value]` will work as well.