# Pure functions with derivatives and list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, pure-function

I have a list

```
list = {x, y, z}
```

and then the following line

```
D[#, list[[2]]] &
```

gives the output

```
\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(list[[2]]\)]#1\) &
```

It still works if I apply it to {x,y,z}, but, unfortunately, it no longer continues if I use it inside another function, like

```
operators[varList_] := 
 Flatten@Table[(varList[[i]] D[#, varList[[i + j]]] &), {i, 1, 
    Length[varList]}, {j, 1, Length[varList] - i}]
```

in the sense that

```
operators[{x, y, z}][[1]]@{x, y, z}
```

gives

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::pkspec1: The expression i+j cannot be used as a part specification.
```

How shold I write it the right way?

Comment: Take a look at: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7758/5478

Comment: @Kuba, thanks, I think it cleared my confusion! Also sorry for not searching hard enough :)

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it's clear now. Not so easy to find an answer in such case.