# How to prevent Table replacing expressions in argument

Tags: evaluation

I have a function called `velocitySolver`, which takes in a list of geometric parameters as well as a condition involving those geometric parameters. Therefore, if I call this function by itself it works as expected:

```
In[1]  = velocitySolver[{.2,.4},condition[[1]]]
Out[1] = {{-3.1164, 0.0251961}, {0.000143856, -0.000143856}}
```

For reference, the condition look like

```
condition = (1 - 4 q^2)^2 (-19 - 88 q^2 + 144 q^4 + 12 (1 - 4 q^2)^2 Cos[a] + (-1 - 8 q^2 + 48 q^4) Cos[2 a])^2 Cos[a] + 12 (-1 - 20 q^2 + 80 q^4 + 64 q^6) Cos[3 a] + Cos[4 a]) Sin[a]^2 > 0
```

However, when I call this function in `Table` I run into some problems

```
In[1]  = Table[velocitySolver[{q,a},condition[[1]]],{q,.2,.4,.1},{a,.2,.4,.1}]
Out[1] = Part: Part specification False[[1]] is longer than the depth of the object.
```

This appears to be because `Table` is applying its arguments as a rule to `condition` before actually evaluating my function. I know I could just use a different variable name but for consistency I was wondering if there was any way to suppress this behavior and allow the `condition` to be passed as a symbolic expression.

Comment: Easier to get an answer if you supply the code for your `velocitySolver` function.

Comment: Additionally, `condition` appears to have a missing parenthesis.

Comment: I think this is close to duplicate to [function in table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7756/function-in-table). From there the favorite answer is to use `With` to inject the condition into the function in the table.

Answer (score 1):

An extended comment ...

Answering the OP has a couple of issues:

We don't (as of this post) know what his function, `velocitySolver` actually does and

As posted, the OP's definition of `condition` apparently has a missing parenthesis.

```
condition = (1 - 4 q^2)^2 (-19 - 88 q^2 + 144 q^4 + 12 (1 - 4 q^2)^2 Cos[a] + (-1 - 8 q^2 + 48 q^4) Cos[2 a])^2 Cos[a] + 12 (-1 - 20 q^2 + 80 q^4 + 64 q^6) Cos[3 a] + Cos[4 a]) Sin[a]^2 > 0
```

The above said, if one makes a guess about where the missing parenthesis would go, e.g.,

```
condition2 = (1 - 4 q^2)^2 (-19 - 88 q^2 + 144 q^4 + 12 (1 - 4 q^2)^2 Cos[a] + (-1 - 8 q^2 + 48 q^4) Cos[2 a])^2 Cos[a] + 12 (-1 - 20 q^2 + 80 q^4 + 64 q^6) (Cos[3 a] + Cos[4 a]) Sin[a]^2 > 0
```

Then it looks like `Table` will work, e.g.,

```
Table[velocitySolver[{q, a}, 
  condition2[[1]]], {q, .2, .4, .1}, {a, .2, .4, .1}]

{{velocitySolver[{0.2, 0.2}, True[[1]]], 
  velocitySolver[{0.2, 0.3}, True[[1]]], 
  velocitySolver[{0.2, 0.4}, True[[1]]]}, 
 {velocitySolver[{0.3, 0.2}, True[[1]]], 
  velocitySolver[{0.3, 0.3}, True[[1]]], 
  velocitySolver[{0.3, 0.4}, True[[1]]]}, 
 {velocitySolver[{0.4, 0.2}, True[[1]]], 
  velocitySolver[{0.4, 0.3}, True[[1]]], 
  velocitySolver[{0.4, 0.4}, True[[1]]]}}
```

Comment: So the code for `velocitySolver` is really irrelevant - the condition typo is my bad though. The problem with the output you have produced is that it is evaulating the condition in the argument and not passing the symbolic version to the function, where it is needed still in symbolic form.

Comment: @JamesVR -- Again, I suggest you post the code for `velocitySolver` or at least some simplified version of it so someone can fully test any proposed solution.  Additionally, please edit your original post to correct `condition`.  All this just makes it easier to get useful answers.