# Method that can be used to collect the variables of a function

Tags: functions

Suppose we have a function `f[x, y, z]` and we want to get all its variables `Sequence[x,y,z]`, what method can we use then? The only one that I can come up with is like this:

```
f[x, y, z] /. func_[vars___] -> Sequence[vars]
```

But it is not very elegant from my point of view. Is there any more suitable method? Thanks!

Comment: How about `Sequence @@ f[x, y, z]`?

Comment: Yes, this is more concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one thing `Sequence` is applied automatically to a raw sequence (such as `vars`) if no other head is found, therefore:

```
f[x, y, z] /. _[vars___] :> vars
```

> ```
> Sequence[x, y, z]
> ```

This is similar to what I have been calling the ["injector pattern"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121) and as you can see from that thread it has value in cases where `Sequence @@ f[x, y, z]` would not avail you, specifically inside symbols that will hold `Sequence` objects.

---

It is hard to guess your application from the question but you can also define a function, perhaps with additional conditions or handling of multiple forms of input, such as:

```
varSeq[expr_] := 
 With[{vars = Variables @ expr}, Sequence @@ vars /; MatchQ[vars, {__Symbol}]]

varSeq[_@vars__Symbol] := vars
```

Now:

```
f[x, y, z] // varSeq
```

> ```
> Sequence[x, y, z]
> ```

```
(x + y)^2 + 3 z^2 - y z + 7 // varSeq
```

> ```
> Sequence[x, y, z]
> ```

---

Incidentally if you like terse coding you can also make use of `SlotSequence`, short form `##`, as in:

```
## & @@ f[x, y, z]
```

which is equivalent to `Sequence @@ f[x, y, z]` in most cases.

Comment: Now there are two more ways to achieve the goal, Thanks!

Comment: @saturasl Thanks for the Accept.  In the future consider waiting longer (I like 24 hours) to give everyone a chance to read the question and answer before it appears "concluded."  Since you gave the Accept I added a couple of other things to my answer to try to cover other scenarios.

Comment: Yes, your additional answer together with PlatoManiac's answer makes this thread valueable for reading.

Answer (score 5):

Probably irrelevant but I thought you have some function defined in the Global` context and you want to get the list of its variables. If that is the case I came up with this messy solution.

Suppose you have defined a function like the following somewhere in a notebook and the definition for the symbol `fun` is available to the kernel as well as not `Protected`. I am defining the following example function using `Module` but one can also use `Block`.

```
Clear[f];
fun[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{val},
   val = RandomReal[1, 3];
   val . {x, y, z}
   ];
```

> {x,y,z}

Then you can get the arguments of `fun` using the following

```
((DownValues[fun])[[1]] /. 
RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[a___],b_] :> (Extract[a, 1, Hold] /. Hold[c_[vars___]] :> List@vars))
```

> {x_, y_, z_}

If you want you can easily convert those pattern into `Symbol` using `First /@%`.

From the comments a more robust solution came out credit to Mr. Wizard.

```
Cases[ DownValues[fun], HoldPattern[fun][vars__] :> {vars}, -1 ] /.
Verbatim[Pattern][name_, _] :> name
```

Comment: Your answer goes deep into the core language, and this is very valueable to me, thanks!

Comment: @saturasl You are welcome.

Comment: Your method as written is not robust in all cases, for example `f[x_, y_, z_] /; something := . . .`; it also doesn't address multiple definitions.  For the simple case it is shorter to write:  `DownValues[fun][[1, 1]] /. _@_@vars___ :> {vars}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you are right! I was sure my solution will not be general. But do think it is possible to have a solution that works for all type of function definition? it will be good to know.

Comment: (1) I didn't mean to disparage your answer; only to let new users know that it has limitations. (2) I expect there would still be corner cases that would slip through the cracks but something fairly general should be possible; here's a first attempt: `Cases[
  DownValues[fun],
  HoldPattern[fun][vars__] :> {vars},
  -1
  ] /. Verbatim[Pattern][name_, _] :> name`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No question of disparaging, your comment is very constructive indeed! I appreciate your effort as now we have got a more general solution. Thx a lot.

Comment: I didn't interpret this question as being about extracting parameters from DownValues but that is an interesting question in itself.  My "first attempt" is also hardly robust.  If this interests you I suggest you ask a question of your own.  If you do, be specific about what should be returned as definitions can be quite complex and varied, with nested patterns, conditions, etc.