# Uniformly distributed n-dimensional probability vectors over a simplex

Tags: random, geometry

What's the right way to generate a random probability vector $p={p_1,\ldots,p_n} \in {(0,1)}^n$ where $\sum_i p_i=1$, uniformly distributed over the $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex?

What I have is

```
Intervals = Table[{0, 1}, {i, n}]
RandomPoint := Block[{a},
    a = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[Intervals]];
    a/Total[a]];
```

But I am unsure that this is correct. In particular, I'm unsure that it's any different from:

```
RandomPoint := Block[{a},
    a = Table[Random[], {i, n}];
    a/Total[a]];
```

And the latter clearly will not distribute vectors uniformly. Is the first code the right one?

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13038/vectors-with-a-certain-magnitude-in-mathematica) may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, @SjoerdC.deVries. That question seems to suggest that my first code is also incorrect? I'm assuming that that bunch of smart guys would have stumbled upon it.

Comment: Perhaps `DirichletDistribution` might help?

Comment: That question involved points on a sphere. Your constraint of $\sum{p_i}=1$ is different.

Comment: I agree with chuy. From [wikipedia: Dirichlet Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Special_cases), we have: "When alpha = 1, the symmetric Dirichlet distribution is equivalent to a uniform distribution over the open standard K-1-simplex, i.e. it is uniform over all points in its support". Using `DirichletDistribution` is most likely then also the best implementation for most purposes.

Comment: Related: [Generate regularly spaced points from the surface of simplexes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27768/89).

Comment: Some folks here might find this StackOverflow duplicate useful (which is asking exactly the same question, but from a computer science perspective). You'll find the answer (to use the Dirichlet) is the same as well, but with a Python implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659858/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-summing-to-1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`#/Total[#,{2}]&@Log@RandomReal[{0,1},{m,n}]` will give you a sample of `m` points from a uniform distribution over an `n-1`-dimensional regular simplex. (An equilateral triangle is a 2-dimensional regular simplex.)  Here's what `m = 2000, n = 3` should look like, where `{x,y} = {p[[2]]-p[[1]], Sqrt@3*p[[3]]}` are the barycentric coordinates of the 3-element probability vector `p`:

[image]

Here's what you get if you omit the `Log@` and normalize Uniform(0,1) variables, which is what both of the OP's examples do:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain in what respects does this behave differently from RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]]?

Comment: See for yourself. Try it with `n = 2` and make a histogram of `p[[1]]`. Or use `n = 3` and `ListPlot` the barycentric coordinates: `{x,y} = {p[[2]]-p[[1]],Sqrt@3*p[[3]]}`.

Comment: Yes, the difference is clear -- see my answer below. Actually, I meant for you to explain the difference in algorithmic terms, or perhaps provide pointers to a textbook explanation of why your method is doing what it's doing.

Comment: I generate a Dirichlet distribution in which all the concentration parameters are 1. See the link that Jacob provided, then scroll down to [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Gamma_distribution) and remember that the log of a Uniform(0,1) variable is proportional to a Gamma variable with shape parameter 1.

Comment: You can also use Mathematica's built-in `DirichletDistribution`: `points = RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1}], 2000] /. 
   v_?VectorQ :> {v[[2]] - v[[1]], Sqrt[3] (1 - Total[v])};` and then `ListPlot[points]`.

Comment: Amazing!  Does anyone have a prove that this distribution is uniform on the simplex?  It passes every stat sampling test I tried, but I still can't prove it's right.  I posted this question on the Math page too.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235192/prove-this-method-generates-uniform-points-on-the-simplex

Answer (score 11):

Starting in M10.2, you can just use [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint):

```
pts=RandomPoint[Simplex[{{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{1,0,0}}], 1000];
Graphics3D[Point[pts]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's a slick capability.

Answer (score 10):

Old question, but I didn't see this method. Generates $n$ points uniformly randomly distributed on a simplex embedded in $d$ dimensions.

```
    genSimplex[n_, d_] := 
       Table[Differences[Sort[Flatten[{0, RandomReal[1, d – 1], 1}]]], {n}];
```

The algorithm generates points that are randomly distributed on an outer face of a simplex. The way to generate them is, for a d-dimensional problem…

1. Generate d-1 uniformly distributed random values in the range [0,1]
2. Add a 0 and a 1 to the list
3. Sort the list
4. Extract a list of the differences between the elements

You now have a list of random values that sum to 1 (so they are on a plane that is defined by points that sum to one) and that are otherwise independent of each other, so their dispersion is uniform.

Updating the answer with a picture of example data with 1,000 points.

[image]

This topic is well-covered here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010837/sample-uniformly-at-random-from-an-n-dimensional-unit-simplex

Comment: This is more or less what I came up with on my own, but then I found this Question page while looking for a more efficient way!