# Generating visually pleasing circle packs

Tags: graphics, generative-art, packing

EDIT: *(my conclusion and thank you note)* I want to thank you all guys for this unexpected intellectual and artistic journey. Hope you had fun and enjoyed it the same as I did.

---

I would like to generate a `circle pack` that mimics this: *(don't pay attention on numbers, and colors at all, at the moment I am interested in circle positions and radii only)*

[image]

or this:

[image]

I am new in Mathematica, could you give me some guidance? Thnx.

*EDIT: The question was strictly for planar case (and remains so), however I see @Jacob Akkerboom in his answer added a solution for 3D generalization (thanks!), and, speaking of that, I just want here to bring to your attention this picture:*

[image]

*EDIT 2: There are some applications of circle packing in irregular shapes, like this: (author Jerome St Claire, handpainted)*

[image]

*... and a font called Dotted: (author Maggie Janssen)*

[image]

*... and some logos:*

[image]

*... garden design:*

[image]

*... infographics:*

[image]

*... and these hypnotic images: (from [percolatorapp](http://www.percolatorapp.com/))*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can take a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/ComputationalGeometry/CirclePacking.nb) and [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CirclesPackedInACircle/) as a start.

Comment: Somewhat related is a [word cloud](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2334/89). Functions used there could be easily adapted to disks.

Comment: randomly place the largest circles, then place successively smaller ones where they can fit.  Its quite straigntforward, and really this feels like a "give me some code" question..

Comment: Thanks for links above, I'll try to find some ideas there. @george2079, no, its not that straightforward. I have a version in another language that is my test bed, it produces a solid output, but I want a little intellectual stimulation from other people here, in order to create a working and beautiful solution at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure the irregular shapes and fonts are not hand-made...

Comment: Shapes are handmade. They are paintings sold like any other paintings. The author says he needs around 4 hours to make one (if I remember well, maybe I am mistaken).

Comment: Off-topic here admittedly, but I'm posting this Gist just in case anyone finds this page when looking for a JS solution to the same problem (as I did). This script loads an SVG shape and generates the circles to fit within it.
https://gist.github.com/gouldingken/8d0b7a05b0b0156da3b8

Comment: @goulding I have seen javascript snippets on this site before a few times, and generally such a comparison is appreciated. I downloaded your files, but simply opening index.html in a browser did not display anything for me. I changed the path js/main.js to circlePackShape.js but that didnt work. Maybe this is really basic stuff, but still it would be nice for our users if you could make it easier to run for a js novice. If you don't want to put a readme on the github because you also have other audiences in mind, perhaps you can post an answer here. <temporary message>

Comment: _don't pay attention on numbers, and colors at all_ What numbers and colors are you talking about? :o)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

replacing `RandomReal` function in István's code with

```
u = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0,1 - ((1 - 2 min)/(max - min) (r - min) + 2 min)}]]
```

leads to non-uniform distribution  [image]

Randomization for the angle can also be non-uniform:

```
randomPoint = 
  Compile[{{r, _Real}}, 
   Module[{u = 
      RandomVariate[
       UniformDistribution[{0, 
         1 - (-((1 - 2 min)/(max - min)) (r - min) + 1)}]], 
     a = RandomVariate[
       UniformDistribution[{π/(max - min)^(1/10) (r - min)^(1/10),
          2 π - π/(max - min)^(1/10) (r - min)^(
           1/10)}]]}, {Sqrt@u*Cos[a 2 Pi], Sqrt@u*Sin[a 2 Pi]}], 
   Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

[image]

The same applies to color. I think that after playing for long enough with these distributions you may even get some beautiful shapes. The real challenge would be to build new compilable distributions based on some graphics, like the figures in your example, or even some edge-detected pictures.

**Edit** (thanks to Simon Woods).
The same idea may be implemented much easier using Simon's approach. We just have to make the radius choice dependent on the distance to the border. Inside the main loop replace the definition of `r`:

```
r = Min[max, d, m Exp[-(d/m)^0.2]]
```

This way the code respects fine details of the shape. You can see the the elephant's tail is drawn in small circles, which is common sense.

[image]

And it takes about 40 seconds to render all the zigs and zags of Norway's shoreline (set `imagesize`to 500, `max=10`, `min=0.5`, `pad=0.2`).

[image]

Further, changing Simon's definition of `m` by adding a background value we can create distinguishable shapes in a pool of small circles:

```
distance = 
  Compile[{{pt, _Real, 1}, {centers, _Real, 2}, {radii, _Real, 1}}, 
    (Sqrt[Abs[First@# - First@pt]^2 + Abs[Last@# - Last@pt]^2] & /@ centers) - radii,
      Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

max = 20;(*largest disk radius*)
min = 0.5;(*smallest disk radius *)
pad = 1;(*padding between disks*)
color = ColorData["DeepSeaColors"];
timeconstraint = 10;
shape = Binarize@ColorNegate@ImageCrop@Rasterize@Style["A", FontSize -> 1000];
centers = radii = {};
Module[{dim, dt, pt, m, d, r},
 dim = ImageDimensions[shape];
 dt = DistanceTransform[shape];
 TimeConstrained[While[True,
   While[
    While[
     pt = RandomReal[{1, #}] & /@ dim;
     (m = 3 + ImageValue[dt, pt]) < min];
    (d = Min[distance[pt, centers, radii]] - pad) < min];
   r = Min[max, d, m];
   centers = Join[centers, {pt}];
   radii = Join[radii, {r}]
   ], timeconstraint]]

Graphics[{color@RandomReal[], #} & /@ MapThread[Disk, {centers, radii}]]
```

[image]

And after that we can finally get to coloring (again, this is a modification of Simon's code):

```
distance = Compile[{{pt, _Real, 1}, {centers, _Real, 2}, {radii, _Real,1}}, (Sqrt[Abs[First@# - First@pt]^2 + Abs[Last@# - Last@pt]^2] & /@centers) - radii, Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
max = 8;(*largest disk radius*)
min = 2;(*smallest disk radius*)
pad = 1.5;(*padding between disks*)
color1 = ColorData["Aquamarine"];
color2 = ColorData["SunsetColors"];
timeconstraint = 10;
background = 7;

shape = Binarize@ColorNegate@Rasterize@Style["74", Bold, Italic, FontFamily -> "PT Serif", FontSize -> 250];
centers = radii = colors = {};
Module[{dim, dt, pt, m, d, r}, dim = ImageDimensions[shape];
 dt = DistanceTransform[shape];
 TimeConstrained[
 While[True, While[While[pt = RandomReal[{1, #}] & /@ (2 dim);
    (m = If[Norm[pt - dim] < 200, background, 0] + If[pt[[1]] < dim[[1]] 3/2 && pt[[1]] > dim[[1]]/2 && pt[[2]] < dim[[2]] 3/2 && pt[[2]] > dim[[2]]/2, ImageValue[dt, pt - dim/2], 0]) < min];
    (d = Min[distance[pt, centers, radii]] - pad) < min];
    r = Min[max, d, m ];
    centers = Join[centers, {pt}];
    radii = Join[radii, {r}];
    colors =Join[colors, {Blend[{color2@RandomReal[{0.4, 0.7}], color1@RandomReal[{0.4, 0.7}]}, Piecewise[{{1/max*(m - background), m < background + max/2}, {1, m >= background + max/2}}]]}]];, timeconstraint]]

Graphics[MapThread[{#1, Disk[#2, #3]} &, {colors, centers, radii}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like the first one, it reminds me on a scene from movie "The Lawnmower Man".

Comment: Wow, for A in a sea of small circles!

Comment: Now make the background of the 74 a `Disk` and you win :)

Comment: @Öskå you got it, Sir!

Answer (score 76):

A simple algorithm that measures the distance of existing disks from a new, candidate disk, while decreasing radius size.

The following two functions generate a random point in the unit disk and measures the distance to all existing disks.

```
randomPoint = Compile[{{r, _Real}}, Module[
   {u = RandomReal@{0, 1 - 2 r}, a = RandomReal@{0, 2 Pi}},
   {Sqrt@u*Cos[a 2 Pi], Sqrt@u*Sin[a 2 Pi]}],
   Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
distance = Compile[{{pt, _Real, 1}, {centers, _Real, 2}, {radii, _Real, 1}},
   (Sqrt[Abs[First@# - First@pt]^2 + Abs[Last@# - Last@pt]^2] & /@ centers) - radii,
   Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];


max = .08; (* largest disk radius *)
min = 0.005; (* smallest disk radius and step size *)
pad = 0.005; (* padding between disks *)
tolerance = 1000; (* wait this many rejections before decreasing radius *)
color = ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"];

centers = radii = {};
Do[failed = 0;
 While[failed < tolerance,
  pt = randomPoint@r;
  dist = distance[pt, centers, radii];
  If[Min@dist > r + pad,
   centers = Join[centers, {pt}];
   radii = Join[radii, {r}];,
   failed++;
   ]];, {r, max, min, -min}]

Graphics[{color@RandomReal[], #} & /@ MapThread[Disk, {centers, radii}],
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled@.02, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By increasing tolerance one can achieve more dense packings, using of course more time. With various min/max radius values and paddings, I got the following packings:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Concerning other, possibly irregular shapes**

Since OP requested other shapes, here is my solution for any, possibly irregular polygon. While the `distance` function remains intact, this approach requires a new `randomPoint` function that draws random points from the $(x, y)$ range of the polygon coordinates from inside the shape (thanks to [rm -rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/89)).

The function `randomPoint` expects a single polygon (with no holes) or a list of polygons (where the first is the outer boundary shape and the rest are the holes):

```
randomPoint[r_, {in_Polygon, ex___Polygon}] := Module[{p, range},
   range = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ Transpose@First@in;
   While[(p = RandomReal /@ range; Not@And[
       Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[in, p], 
       And @@ (Not@Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[#, p] & /@ {ex})]
     ),]; p];
randomPoint[r_, poly_Polygon] := randomPoint[r, {poly}];

max = 1; (* largest disk radius *)
d = 0.01; (* smallest disk radius and step size *)
pad = 0; (* padding between disks *)
tolerance = 300; (* wait for this many rejections before decreasing radius *)
color = ColorData@"BlueGreenYellow";
shape = Polygon@N@(First@First@CountryData["Australia", "SchematicPolygon"]);

centers = radii = {};
Do[failed = 0;
 While[failed < tolerance,
  pt = randomPoint[r, shape];
  dist = distance[pt, centers, radii];
  If[Min@dist > r + pad,
   centers = Join[centers, {pt}];
   radii = Join[radii, {r}];,
   failed++;
   ]];, {r, max, d, -d}];

{
 Graphics[{EdgeForm@Gray, FaceForm@White, shape}, ImageSize -> 300],
 Graphics[{color@RandomReal[], #} & /@ MapThread[Disk, {centers, radii}],
    ImageSize -> 300]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For shapes with holes, I used [Szabolcs's conversion to polygons](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/642/89):

```
shape = Block[{fun, g, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax},
   fun = ListInterpolation@
     Rasterize[Style[Rotate["β", -Pi/2], FontSize -> 24, 
        FontFamily -> "Times"], "Data", ImageSize -> 300][[All, All, 1]];
   {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = fun@"Domain";
   g = RegionPlot[fun[x, y] < 128, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
     PlotPoints -> 50, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
   Cases[Normal@g, Line[x___] :> Polygon@x, Infinity]
   ];
```

Result with `{max = 3, d = .05}` is:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! It looks great, it gives natural, even, feel. However, I believe it would look even better if there is always at least a small padding (2 or 3 pixels) between two circles.

Comment: @VividD You can easily have that by increasing `pad`.

Comment: Beautiful! Will check it out!

Comment: Can you also implement a region function so that you can pack the disks into any shape?

Comment: I got very good results with padding 0.008, failed < 5000, and initial radius .05. That said, please let me just suggest an idea: Condition "failed < 5000" is used for all radii. This means that the largest (first) circles will take a lot of space (and as you can see in the first example, this is not the case in original pic). Maybe "failed < 5000" should be "failed < 10" for the first pass, "failed < 100" for the second pass, and "failed < 1000" for all other passes... (Numbers 10, 100, 1000 are just guesses)

Comment: @rm -rf, that's a wonderful idea!

Comment: @István Zachar, OK :)

Comment: @rm-rf, Vivid: If you have an equation for the shape (like [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33666/89)), its quite easy to modify `randomPoint`.

Comment: @István Zachar, thats great effort for irregular shape of Australia. However, if you superimpose both images with the right scaling, circles should be in the interior. It looks something is illogical here, either algorithm allows circles to be partially outside the shape, or something else. Its not enough that only center is inside the shape. But thanks in any case!

Comment: @VividD Nothing illogical: while for a disk of radius `R` it is quite easy to shoot random circles of radius `r` to an actually smaller-radius disk `R-2r` to keep disks inside the main disk, the same for an irregular shape is a bit more complicated. So I've sacrificed it for speed.

Comment: @IstvánZachar, Ok, I thought so (and you wanted I guess simplicity too). One needs here to compute distance to the polygon for each candidate circle. Given other comparisons, would that hurt speed that much?

Comment: @VividD Well, it would hurt _my_ speed much: I've already spent two days on this while I have a deadline to meet :)

Comment: Ok, thats whole different story... ;)

Comment: Why not use a built-in `inPolyQ` from here: [How to check if a 2D point is in a polygon?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405) ? :)

Comment: Let's say a country has a lake, and also an island in that lake. This case would be covered, right?

Comment: @VividD Not at the moment, but it is quite easy to handle with logical operators in `randomPoint`. There is no one algorithm that can cover every situation so you have to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Congratulations on a second Populist badge. :-)

Comment: @rm-rf now in V10 we have [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html)

Answer (score 42):

This methods relies on generating random circles and then removing circles that overlap with circles that were found earlier.

I suppose one should really divide the surface into bins and only check for overlaps between subsets of the circles. Especially if there is an upper bound to the size of a circle (the bound in my code is 1, which is not practical). This would be an improvement.

Here is the code

```
nn = 1*^5;
randRsPrefilter = RandomReal[1, nn];

randRadiiPrefilter = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[8, 200], nn];

filter = Compile[{{radii1, _Real, 1}, {radii2, _Real, 1}}, 
   Block[{len, remaining}, len = Length@radii1;
    remaining = ConstantArray[1, len];
    Do[If[radii1[[i]] + radii2[[i]] > 1., remaining[[i]] = 0], {i, 
      len}];
    remaining]];

filt = filter[randRsPrefilter, randRadiiPrefilter];

randRs = Pick[randRsPrefilter, filt, 1];
randRadii = Pick[randRadiiPrefilter, filt, 1];

randAngles = RandomReal[2 Pi, Length@randRs];

toCoords = 
  Compile[{{l1, _Real, 1}, {l2, _Real, 1}}, 
   Table[l1[[i]] {Cos[l2[[i]]], Sin[l2[[i]]]}, {i, Length@l1}]];

coords = toCoords[randRs, randAngles];

overlapFilter = 
  Compile[{{coords, _Real, 2}, {radii, _Real, 1}, {start, _Integer}}, 
   Block[{res, curr, len, remaining, test, j}, len = Length@coords;
    remaining = ConstantArray[1, len];
    j = 1;
    test = True;
    Do[If[remaining[[i]] == 1, test = True;
      j = Max[start, i + 1];
      While[test, 
       If[Sqrt[Total[(coords[[i]] - coords[[j]])^2]] < 
         radii[[i]] + radii[[j]] + 0.01, remaining[[j]] = 0];
       If[j == len, test = False, j++;]]], {i, 1, len - 1}];
    remaining], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

overlapFilt = overlapFilter[coords, randRadii, 1];

goodCoords = Pick[coords, overlapFilt, 1];
goodRadii = Pick[randRadii, overlapFilt, 1];

goodPairs = Transpose[{goodCoords, goodRadii}];

Graphics[Disk @@@ goodPairs]
```

Output

[image]

**3D version output**

This only requires a slight a slight modification of the code, one only has to convert spherical coordinates to euclidean, rather than polar to euclidean. The distance function used in the overlapFilter function is sufficiently abstracted to deal with this.

[image]

Comment: I like this method, because it is somehow fair. I had some distribution in mind and I didn't cheat by putting new circles between old ones in an artificial way. But I guess that has it's cost, `Count[overlapFilt[[-3000 ;;]], 1]` gives 2, which means that in the end almost all circles get rejected.

Comment: I like your method too! This will help me a lot, since I am new in Mathematica. The algorithm is short, simple, easy to modify, perfect for me. Thanks!

Comment: @VividD Please **do not** edit answers to ask a question or leave a comment. Writing it in this space (as a comment) is the right thing to do.

Comment: @rm -rf OK, no problem... :)

Comment: Jacob, check your gmail :)

Answer (score 41):

Here's another shape-packing one, with a binary image used to define the shape to be filled. I use a `DistanceTransform` on the image, which provides a convenient way to measure the distance from any point to the boundary of the shape.

I've used Istvan's distance function, but instead of choosing a spot size and then locating somewhere to put it, I choose a location and then determine the spot size subject to the constraints.

The packing continues for a fixed time, using `TimeConstrained` - the longer you allow the code to run the more densely packed the shape will be.

```
distance = 
  Compile[{{pt, _Real, 1}, {centers, _Real, 2}, {radii, _Real, 1}}, 
    (Sqrt[Abs[First@# - First@pt]^2 + Abs[Last@# - Last@pt]^2] & /@ centers) - radii,
      Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

max = 5;(*largest disk radius*)
min = 1;(*smallest disk radius *)
pad = 1;(*padding between disks*)
color = ColorData["CandyColors"];
timeconstraint = 10;

shape = Binarize@ColorNegate@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtJoA.png"]
```

[image]

```
centers = radii = {};
Module[{dim, dt, pt, m, d, r},
 dim = ImageDimensions[shape];
 dt = DistanceTransform[shape];
 TimeConstrained[While[True,
   While[
    While[
     pt = RandomReal[{1, #}] & /@ dim;
     (m = ImageValue[dt, pt]) < min];
    (d = Min[distance[pt, centers, radii]] - pad) < min];
   r = Min[max, d, m];
   centers = Join[centers, {pt}];
   radii = Join[radii, {r}]
   ], timeconstraint]]

Graphics[{color@RandomReal[], #} & /@ MapThread[Disk, {centers, radii}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This one is beautiful. Contours of the original are clearly visible.

Answer (score 27):

The idea is to

1. Choose a random white spot on a binarized image.
2. Try to fit as large circle as possible (of the givens ones) in this position.
3. If no circle fits at this position, choose a new random position. If there are n positions in a row for which you cannot fit a circle then terminate the process.

Instead of working with graphics primitives and the position of circles and their radii I work with the image matrix directly.

Code:

```
padding = 1;
circles = {Position[DiskMatrix[# + padding], 1] - # - padding, 
     Position[DiskMatrix[#], 1] - #} & /@ {15, 12, 10, 6, 3, 1};

shape = DiskMatrix[250];
space = Position[shape, 1];
i = 0;

While[i < 1000,
 pt = RandomChoice[space]; placed = False;
 Do[
   occupied = pt + # & /@ c[[1]];
   If[Length@occupied == Length@Intersection[space, occupied],
    space = Complement[space, occupied];
    shape = 
     ReplacePart[shape, 
      pt + # & /@ c[[2]] -> ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]@RandomReal[] /. 
       RGBColor[r_, g_, b_] :> {r, g, b}];
    placed = True; i = 0; Break[]
    ], {c, circles}]
  If[! placed, i++];
 ]

shape = ReplacePart[shape, Position[shape, 1, {2}] -> {1, 1, 1}];
shape = ReplacePart[shape, Position[shape, 0, {2}] -> {1, 1, 1}];

shape // Image
```

Adjustable parameters are the paddings, the size of the circles and for how long it continues to try to pack the shape.

With the color scheme `BlueGreenYellow` and `shape = DiskMatrix[250]` we get

[image: demo1]

With the color scheme `DeepSeaColors` and

```
shape = ImageData@ColorNegate@ImageCrop@Binarize@Rasterize@Style["A", FontSize -> 1000];
```

we get

[image: demo2]

Finally, this is a circle packed map of Sweden using the color scheme `DarkTerrain`:

```
shape = ImageData@ColorNegate@Binarize[Rasterize@Show[CountryData["Sweden", "Shape"], ImageSize -> 200],0.99];
```

[image: demo3]

The careful observer will note that the smallest objects are not actually round. Don't worry about this, it's because the smallest object is just one pixel and you can't make a circle out of that. It saved me time to generate the graphics like this, it can easily be fixed by making a larger image and setting the smallest circle to a radius of say three or five, then shrinking the image to whatever size one wants.

Comment: Thanks, amazing!! What I would also like to see is Norway, detailed map, I am interested in how your method handle fjords.

Comment: @VividD The code is available, you can try it out. Just change "Sweden" to "Norway." The larger the image the more detail you can capture, afterwards you can scale it down.

Comment: @VividD see the edit in my post. Seems to do Norway just fine!

Answer (score 14):

Here's a pretty general way of filling an arbitrary shape with circle packs that starts with an arbitrary black and white image.

Start with a grid of points and perturb them (the size of the perturbation will dictate the variability in the sizes of the circles). Then find how far it is to the nearest point -- each point will then be grown into a disk with diameter equal to this distance. First for a square region:

```
n = 10;
tab = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -n, n}, {j, -n, n}], 1];
pts = tab + RandomReal[{-0.3, 0.3}, {Length[tab], 2}];
nf[x_] := Nearest[pts, x, 2];
radii = EuclideanDistance[nf[pts[[#]]][[1]], nf[pts[[#]]][[2]]] & /@ 
    Range[Length[pts]]/2;
Graphics[Table[{RGBColor[RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]], 
   Disk[pts[[i]], radii[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[pts]}]]
```

[image]

To control the shape, begin with an image that is white wherever we wish the circles to be. For example, consider the horse

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6OUl.png"]
```

[image]

It is easy to apply the above method to a simplified (downsampled) version of the horse. The mask removes all the circles in the black area leaving only the circles in the white.

```
imgSimp = Downsample[ImageData[img], 10];
imgDim = Dimensions[imgSimp];
tab = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, imgDim[[1]]}, {j, 1, imgDim[[2]]}], 1];
mask = Flatten[Partition[tab Flatten[imgSimp], imgDim[[2]]], 1];
pts = mask + RandomReal[{-0.3, 0.3}, {Length[mask], 2}];
nf[x_] := Nearest[pts, x, 2];
radii = EuclideanDistance[nf[pts[[#]]][[1]], nf[pts[[#]]][[2]]] & /@ 
    Range[Length[pts]]/2;
Rotate[Graphics[
  Table[{RGBColor[g = RandomReal[], g, g], 
    Disk[pts[[i]], radii[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[pts]}]], -Pi/2]
```

[image]

Comment: What's your meaning of the `mask = Flatten[Partition[tab, imgDim[[2]]] img, 1];`And your `imgDim[[2]]] img` is a typo?

Comment: If change the `mask` to`mask=Pick[Partition[tab,imgDim[[2]]],Map[Flatten,imgSimp,{-3}],1.]//Level[#,{2}]&;`.The code will work in my computer. And I found a strange thing that if you run`{Downsample[ImageData[img],3]//Dimensions,Downsample[ImageData[img],4]//Dimensions}`,you'll get `{{77,80,2},{58,60,1}}`

Comment: @yode -- I'm not sure what changed, but I have now fixed the mask definition so that it removes all the circles in the black area (leaving only the circles in the white). Thanks for alerting me to the problem!

Answer (score 5):

Share a solution just applicable to 10.4 or later version.The code is very terse,but it seem to have some mysterious bug in it.And I have post it [as a discuss](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117732/the-unexpected-behavior-of-region-calculate).Firstly I make a function name of `diskMake`

```
diskMake[region_, n_] := 
 Module[{p, rad, dist, temRegion = region}, SeedRandom[1]; 
  Reap[Do[p = RandomPoint[temRegion]; 
     rad = If[(dist = Abs[SignedRegionDistance[temRegion, p]]) < .2, 
       dist, RandomReal[{.2, Min[{dist, .3}]}]]; 
     temRegion = 
      RegionDifference[temRegion, DiscretizeRegion@Sow[Disk[p, rad]]],
      n]][[-1, -1]]]
```

Generate some disk bounded by a certain region

```
wordRegion = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["21", FontFamily -> "Arial"]], _Text];
diskLarge = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
   RegionDifference[BoundingRegion[wordRegion, "FastBall"], 
    wordRegion];
wordDisk = diskMake[wordRegion, 200];
largerDisk = diskMake[diskLarge, 600];
```

Draw it with diffrence color

```
Graphics[MapThread[
  Transpose[{RandomColor[
      Hue[#1, NormalDistribution[.6, .2], 
       NormalDistribution[.6, .07]], #2 // Length], #2}] &, {{1/3, 
    1/2}, {wordDisk, largerDisk}}]]
```

[image]