# Random non-overlapping disks in a square

Tags: graphics, random, distributions, version-7, generative-art

I've found a nice [code snippet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84997/20144) by @belisarius from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84991/plotting-random-circles-in-a-square), that I'll reproduce here for reference:

```
SeedRandom[5];

f := {RandomReal[{0, 10}, 2], RandomReal[{0.05, 3}]}

l = {f};

While[Length@l < 20, While[k = f;
    Not[And @@ ((# + k)[[2]] < EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], k[[1]]] & /@ 
   l)]];
AppendTo[l, k]];

Graphics[{Circle @@@ l, FaceForm[Transparent], EdgeForm[Red], 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, 0}, {0, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

Now, I would like to add two things to it :

1. All circles (disks) should be randomly colorized (from any color palette),
2. The parts outside the square should be removed, while leaving the disk's part inside.

Also, I would like a denser generator:  all random sized disks should touch its neighbors.

How could we achieve this, using ***Mathematica*** **version 7.0** ?

Comment: Ok, but "I wish it so and so ..." without showing some effort looks too lazy ...

Comment: In addition to the code you mentioned, take a look at the answers proposed for [Generating visually pleasing circle packs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40334/27951).

Comment: I tried some of the codes from that page, but they don't work with Mathematica 7.0.  I don't know how to edit and adapt them to Mma 7.0.

Comment: This gets you the coloring you seek:  `Graphics[{{Hue[RandomReal[]], #} & /@ (Circle @@@ l),
  FaceForm[Transparent], EdgeForm[Red], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, 0}, {0, 0}}]}]`

Comment: This clips your region to the region you seek:  `PlotRange -> {{-.02, 10.02}, {-.02, 10.02}}`

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot.  It's working great.  And changing Circle @@@ l to Disk @@@ l gives a distribution of disks.

Comment: Hmm, how can I use the Aquamarine color palette instead of Hue ?  Probably trivial, but I don't see it.

Comment: Ah yes, it was trivial, sorry about that.  Just change Hue[...] to ColorData["Aquamarine", RandomReal[]].

Comment: The only thing missing is to make the distribution denser.  Disks should be touching their neighbors.  I don't see how to do this.  Any idea ?

Comment: Somewhat related, possibly applicable: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22896/efficiently-filling-area-with-disks-located-at-certain-points

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The trick is to place some random non-overlapping `Disks` in your square area, then use the `DistanceTransform` to find a point in your square area that is the farthest from its nearest disk.  (Such a point will be equidistant from at least two disks--generally three or more disks.)  Place a new disk centered at this point, with its radius equal to the distance to its nearest existing disk.  Iterate this procedure (here 60 times) using `Nest`.  Then merely plot colored `Circle`s with those centers and radii.

What is nice about this algorithm is that it iteratively finds the largest possible circle consistent with the existing circles, and therefore the radii will never increase during iteration.  Note too that it is possible that the algorithm will introduce circles whose centers are on the perimeter of your square area.

```
startingcenters = {{{5, 8}, 1}, {{1, 6}, 2}, {{9, 8}, .5}, 
                   {{8, 2}, .5}, {{1, 1}, 1}}; 
f[centerset_List] := 
 Module[{m = ImageData[
         DistanceTransform[
         Image[
         Graphics[
         Disk @@@ centerset,
         PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}},
         ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}]]]]},
  {{#[[2]]/100, 10 - #[[1]]/100}, Max[m]/100} &@ Position[m , Max[m]][[1]]
  ];
finalcenters = Nest[Union[#, {f[#]}] &, startingcenters, 60];
Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]], #} & /@ (Circle @@@ finalcenters),
  PlotRange -> {{-0.04, 10.04}, {-0.04, 10.04}},
  Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, 0}, {0, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow !  That is very good !  But how do you make the output random at each recompilation ?  For the moment, the code generates exactly the same output as your figure.

Comment: Also, what is the parameter that controls the number of circles in the final output ?

Comment: @Cham The parameter that controls the number of circles in the final output is the third argument of `Nest` (here 60).  Just change that to get more or fewer circles.  The algorithm is deterministic (once the `startingcenters` have been set), so if you want a different image, choose a different set of non-overlapping starting centers.  You can do this algorithmically too, using random seed to choose random centers and radii (but eliminating any disks that overlap).

Comment: @Cham A trivial way to get a different image each time is to set `startingcenters = {{RandomReal[{0,10}],RandomReal[{0,10}]},RandomReal[{0,5}]};`, but that will generally lead to some very big circles.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.  I then suggest to declare the number of circles as a parameter, at the start of the code.

Comment: @Cham Simply define `numCircles = 60;` (or whatever) and place `numCircles` in the third slot of `Nest`.  By the way, doesn't my answer justify a green acceptance check mark?

Comment: Yes, this is what I just done.

Comment: I'll ty the startingcenters for random images...

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting some error message while using the code startingcenters = {{RandomReal[{0, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 10}]}, 
   RandomReal[{0, 5}]};  For example, error message "4.8977563857133095` is not a Graphics primitive or directive."

Comment: @Cham Ah... I forgot an outer bracket.  This works:  `startingcenters = {{{RandomReal[{0, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 10}]}, 
    RandomReal[{1, 4}]}};`

Comment: Wow !  Very nice output !  And yes, you're right, we may get some big circles.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand.  What are these starting numbers : {1, 4}  smallest and biggest starting circles radii I guess ?  Argh, dumb me !  They are the min and max number of starting circles... is that right ?

Comment: How could we define a random set of, say 5, starting non-overlapping circles ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25601/discussion-between-david-g-stork-and-cham).

Comment: How can I reduce the size of all the final disks by a given factor (say 0.9) ?

Comment: @Cham `scaledfinalcenters = {#[[1]],  .9 #[[2]]} & /@ finalcenters` then use the `scaledfinalcenters` in the final plotting.  [Gosh... and *still* no acceptance of my answer!]

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry about the checkmark, I was waiting for other answers, in case someone had another solution (faster compilation ?)

Answer (score 3):

The following code is faster, but has its own problems. That is, for some settings of the radius bounds it is impossible to fit a large number of disks into the square. In addition, there are fewer tangent points than in the answer by @DavidGStork; however, every disk is tangent to at least one other.

The radius of a new disk is the minimum of the distances to all disk centres minus the disk radii. If the minimum is negative then the new centre lies within an existing disk.

```
MinCircleRadius[newCentre_List, circles_List] :=
   Min[Map[Norm[newCentre - #] &, circles[[All, 1]]] - circles[[All, 2]]]
```

Find a new disk with radius between rlo and rhi, within a square of side 10, centred on the origin.

```
FindNewCircle[circles_, rlo_, rhi_] :=
    Block[{c = RandomReal[{-5., 5.}, 2], r},
       While[(r=MinCircleRadius[c, circles])<rlo || r>rhi, c=RandomReal[{-5.,5.},2]];
       {c, r}]
```

Place disks.

```
PackSomeCircles[n_, rlo_, rhi_] :=
   Nest[Flatten[{#, {FindNewCircle[#, rlo, rhi]}}, 1] &,
        {{RandomReal[{-4, 4}, 2], RandomReal[{rlo, rhi}]}}, n]
```

Begin with a small lower bound to avoid impossible fits.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{c},
      SeedRandom[seed];
      c = PackSomeCircles[n, rlo, rhi];
      Graphics[{
         EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}],
         Map[{ColorData[cs, #[[2]]], Apply[Disk, #]} &, c],
         Thickness[0.02], Line[{{-5,-5}, {5,-5}, {5,5}, {-5,5}, {-5,-5}}]
      }, Background -> Gray, PlotRange -> 5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]],
   {{n, 100, "Number of Disks"}, 2, 250, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{rlo, 0.02, "Radius Lower Bound"}, 0.02, 0.99*rhi, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{rhi, 1.0, "Radius Upper Bound"}, 1.01*rlo, 2.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{seed, 1, "Random Seed"}, 1, 2000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{cs, "DarkRainbow", "Colour Scheme"}, ColorData["Gradients"]}]
```

[image: random disk pack]

Answer (score 0):

With the solution above suggested by David G. Stork, I made this complete (?) working solution.

I'm now wondering if it could be improved in some way.  Currently, it's a bit slow.

```
SeedRandom[];

f := {RandomReal[{0, 10}, 2], RandomReal[{0.5, 3}]}
l = {f};

While[Length@l < 10, While[k = f;
    Not[And @@ ((# + k)[[2]] < EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], k[[1]]] & /@l)]];
    AppendTo[l, k]];

Graphics[{Circle @@@ l, FaceForm[Transparent], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, 0}, {0, 0}}]}]

numCircles = 100;

g[centerset_List] := Module[{m = ImageData[DistanceTransform[Image[Graphics[Disk @@@ centerset, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
     ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}]]]]}, {{#[[2]]/100, 10 - #[[1]]/100}, Max[m]/100} &@Position[m, Max[m]][[1]]];

finalcenters = Nest[Union[#, {g[#]}] &, Circle @@@ l, numCircles];

Graphics[{ColorData["Aquamarine", RandomReal[]], #} & /@ (Disk @@@finalcenters), PlotRange -> {{-0.04, 10.04}, {-0.04, 10.04}}, Epilog -> {Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, 0}, {0, 0}}]}]
```

(I'm unable to upload a preview picture from my HD.  The upload interface doesn't work with OS X ?)