# Plotting deformed disks

Tags: plotting, display

I have a list containing the x and y coordinates and the radius of different circles, with some of them overlapping.

I wish to plot the circles in this list. However, the overlapping circles should 'deform', by connecting the intersections of these circles. Therefore, no place is occupied by multiple circles.

Example:

[image: Desired result]

Is this possible in Mathematica?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87676/random-non-overlapping-disks-in-a-square/87694

Comment: Sounds like you want a (weighted) Voronoi diagram...

Comment: @J.M. Voronoi diagram include that white space?

Comment: @yode, no, so you'd want to only replace the intersecting disks with their corresponding Voronoi cells, and leave the nonintersecting ones as they are.