# How do I generate n random numbers with an extra condition

Tags: random

I need to generate `n` random numbers that would sum into `a`. And I can't find an elegant solution here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html .

The only solution I have in my head is to generate random numbers and than include `IF` sentence. But it would take years before Mathematica would find the n random numbers whose sum is exactly a. Any other ideas on how to do this here?

Comment: Reals or integers?  To what interval are the numbers constrained?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69707/5478

Comment: Random numbers of what domain? And for how large of a sum? To what end (why do you "need" this, what problem/purpose does it serve?)

Comment: Let's say n=5, a=60. All numbers are Reals and nonnegative.

Comment: Generate *n* reals (0,1), normalize them, multiply *a* by that, done.

Comment: `Differences@Append[NestList[# + RandomReal[{0, 60 - #}] &, 0, 4], 60]`

Comment: One way to do @ciao's idea: `a Normalize[RandomReal[1, n], Total]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Thanks and plus 1, I'm mobile and cringe at posting code I can't test first, I'm not that good ;-)

Comment: @ciao But this doesn't give a uniform distribution in that triangle: `ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[
  Normalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3], Total],
  {10000}
  ],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 ]`.  In this sense not every triplet generated by this method is equally likely.

Comment: It's kind of like [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)): we really need to agree in what "random" means here *precisely*.

Comment: What @SimonRochester wrote is exactly as needed!

Comment: @skrat Why?  You have three proposals (from ciao, Simon and Praan).  All of them give *very different* distributions.  The question needs to be clarified before we can decide which is the "right" ones.

Comment: From a [memorable answer by Ray Koopman](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33666): `Block[{a = 11, n = 3}, a #/Total[#, {1}] &@Log@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n}]]`.  His answer shows how to get `m` such vectors in one similar efficient call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be able to answer this question, we need to agree what "random" means precisely.  To me, the most reasonable interpretation is [to require a uniform distribution on the $\sum_i x_i = a$ simplex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69707/random-real-numbers-that-sum-up-to-specific-value#comment192794_69729).

This will be satisfied by Praan's solution once we filter tuples containing negative numbers.  Let's illustrate using $a=1$ and $n=3$.

**Praan's** method:

```
pts = Select[
   Append[#, 1 - Total[#]] & /@ RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}],
   Positive[Times @@ #] &
   ];

ListPointPlot3D[
 pts,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or let's just project down to 2D to make things easier to see:

Appropriate basis vectors:

```
a = Normalize[{-1, 1, 0}];
b = Normalize[{-1, -1, 1}];

ListPlot[
 {a.#, b.#} & /@ pts,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The fact that the distribution will be uniform is also clear from the fact that this method is effectively doing a *linear* transformation on points of the form $(x,y,0)$, which are already uniformly distributed within a plane.

**ciao**'s idea (comments) gives a very different distribution:

```
pts = Table[
   Normalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3], Total],
   {10000}
   ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And **Simon Rochester**'s method (comments) produces a distribution that's different from both:

```
pts = Table[
   Differences@Append[NestList[# + RandomReal[{0, 1 - #}] &, 0, 2], 1],
   {10000}
   ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To decide which one is right, we need to agree on the interpretation of random.  To me, the most reasonable interpretation is this: a "random triplet of numbers" means uniform distribution in 3D Euclidean space.  Adding a constraint (i.e they must sum to $a$) should not modify this requirement, i.e. that we need to have uniform distribution in 3D Euclidean space.

**This is only satisfied by Praan's method.**

Comment: Wouldn't this be a dupe of the one you linked to, then?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Yes, it is.  I asked Mr.Wizard to reopen because I was just finishing up typing the answer when it got closed ... and also because I thought that `DirichletDistribution` is not a viable choice for large $n$.  But that doesn't seem to be the case: it's fast even for $n$ as large as 10000.

Comment: Nice experimental setup.

Comment: +1, nice analysis, I concur: poorly defined question, lacking the definition of "random" for the desired result, and with your conclusion in any case.

Answer (score 4):

Generate $n-1$ random numbers first. Then the $n$th number is given by $a$ minus the sum of the $n-1$ randomly generated numbers. Your code could look like this, for example,

```
rTable = RandomReal[{rmin, rmax}, n-1]
AppendTo[rTable, a-Total@rTable]
a == Total@rTable
```

**Edit**

As pointed out by Szabolcs in the comments of this answer, this method fails when the $n$-th number is negative since the OP requested positive numbers (for suitable $a$ and $n$). This can be remedied by selecting only those lists of random numbers where the $n$-th number is positive.

For a nice implementation, see [the answer of Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88662/12908), in which the question is reformulated in terms of a uniform distribution on the $(n-1)$-[simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex) defined by $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_i/a=1$.

Comment: Might want to rethink that re: distribution of the elements themselves...  these are not as "random" as you seem to think...

Comment: To comply with the OP's requirements, you need to ensure additionally that all numbers are positive (e.g. filter out tuples containing negative ones).

Comment: @ciao Could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yup, you're right. Sorry about that. I can't delete my answer though..

Comment: @Praan You can edit it and add the filtering.  No need to delete, just a small correction needed.