# Random sampling of multiple integers with constant sum

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

I want to build a model of 40 geological layers, assuming each layer has equal chance to be one of the four types of rocks and the four types of rocks have equal chance to appear in any layer. The number of layers for the four types of rocks are n1, n2, n3 and n4 respectively. So n1, n2, n3, and n4 must an integer between [0,40] and their sum must be 40. I have tried the following to generate a population of this model. But n1, n2, n3 and n4 have different distributions, which is not correct.

```
nRun = 1000;
sum = 40;
n1 = Table[0, {nRun}];
n2 = n1; n3 = n1; n4 = n1;
Do[
 n1[[iR]] = RandomInteger[{0, sum}];
 n2[[iR]] = RandomInteger[{0, sum - n1[[iR]]}];
 n3[[iR]] = RandomInteger[{0, sum - n1[[iR]] - n2[[iR]]}];
 n4[[iR]] = 40 - n1[[iR]] - n2[[iR]] - n3[[iR]], {iR, 1, nRun}]
```

Could someone help me with it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am fairly sure you stated conflicting goals. If the sum is 40 then the distribution of the values can hardly be uniform in `Range[0,40]`. You will need to better specify what you want. Maybe a random partition uniformly distributed amongst all possible partitions?

Comment: It is a practical physical problem.  I am just not sure how to realized it statistically or mathematically. For example, you have 40 geological layers, assuming the layers can be any of 4 types of rocks. For the 40 layers, the number of layers of each type of rock is n1, n2, n3 or n4.  n1 can be any integer number between 0 to 40, so does n2, n3 and n4. and always n1+n2+n3+n4=40.

Comment: `With[{blocks = Join[{0}, Sort[RandomSample[Range[43], 3]], {44}]},
 Differences[blocks] - 1]` might be what you want.

Comment: V.E's answer is close to what I want, it is a pity that the resulting distributions of the integer variables are normal, not the uniform distribution I preferred.

Comment: (1) See my first comment. You can have a uniform distribution from amongst all possible 4-tuples summing to 40. You cannot have a uniform distribution from amongst all integers 0-40. For starters, every appearance of 40 implies an appearance of three 0s.

Comment: (2) I suspect that the @V.E. method will give what I would regard as the "right" distribution (and I gave that response an upvote).

Comment: (3) The method I indicate, if processed with `Compile`, is somewhat faster though only by a factor of 2 for the stated parameters. Possibly it can be done instead with `RandomInteger` or `RandomReal`, which might give another factor of 2. For a set much larger than 40, or a number of subsets much larger than 4,  it's a different story, since my code is not much dependent on those parameters in terms of speed.

Comment: Hi, Daniel, your short script IS actually what I want. The resulting distribution seems uniform. Thanks a lot! Just that your code seems a bit weird, maybe you can rewrite in more explicit form and put it as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uniformly distributed n-dimensional probability vectors over a simplex](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/uniformly-distributed-n-dimensional-probability-vectors-over-a-simplex). Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88656/

Comment: I have a question. For simplicity consider the case o 5 layers and 2 types of rock (instead of 40 and 5 respectively). Do you want to see each of {0,5},{1,4},{2,3},{3,2},{1,4},{0,5} with equal probability? If so, then what I posted is appropriate. If instead you want to see each rock type appear in each layer with probability 1/2, then the method of @V.E. is the correct approach. These entail very different underlying assumptions and which you want will depend on what you are modeling.

Comment: I think yours results are more physically making sense to me. I have test V.E. simulation results on 40 layers and 4 types of rocks. I did not find any realization that one type of rock can take up more than 25 layers.  What I want is that any combination have equal chance to appear, so that is your answer.  Again, thank you very much for solving my problem.

Comment: I don't know, what problem exactly you are trying to solve, but for your example with different geological layers it makes no sense to me. Each of the 40 layers can be one of four types with equal likelihood. It's then extremely unlikely, that there will be such a heavy bias towards a layer of a specific type. But if every combination needs an equal chance, then sure, you have the answer.

Comment: To @LLlAMnYP and others who voted to close this, I will remark that the integer case is really not the same as the real-valued case in the claimed duplicate. Maybe the latter can be adapted to the former by widening and rounding,  and certainly as is it can give a reasonable approximation away from the simplex boundaries. But this involves some amount of reasoning that is not entirely obvious. This question stands on its own merits. (The issues with the criteria for randomness are a separate issue, seemingly sorted out in various comments.) Anyway, this should be reopened.

Comment: To @LLlAMnYP : Please have a look of my revised question.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I've acknowledged your remark and will try to fill in tomorrow, though so far I have to disagree. Perhaps, admittedly, I *am* missing something.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, as the goalposts have been radically shifted.

Comment: I've got an extensive answer covering various approaches to generate these tuples, as well as comparing their resulting distributions. I'll flag the post, hopefully a mod will open it. It seems, it's generating only further confusion so far :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, LLIAMnYP and others: The post has been reopened :)

Comment: C'mon Yanfon, we've worked long and hard to give both reasonable responses and to reopen this question. Your request to (re)close it is not being helpful. Opening a separate question is of course fine; my point is this should not again be closed.

Comment: @ Daniel. I respect your suggestion. It would be nice to add a link in the new equation to this old equation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a fairly fast code snippet. The idea is to place three demarcators in 43 slots (in general: n+k-1 slots, k-1 demarcators). Then the count between jth and j+1th is the number that goes in the j+1th position of the result, where j runs from 0 to k (and there is no 0th position in the result).

```
sample = Compile[{{total, _Integer}, {len, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   Table[With[{blocks = 
       Join[{0}, 
        Sort[RandomSample[Range[total + len - 1], len - 1]], {total + 
          len}]},
     Differences[blocks] - 1], n], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Generate a million of them.

```
sampleSize = 10^6;
Timing[samples2 = sample[40, 4, sampleSize];]

(* Out[111]= {1.181074, Null} *)
```

The first few:

```
In[112]:= samples2[[1 ;; 20]]

(* Out[112]= {{1, 9, 4, 26}, {13, 16, 3, 8}, {7, 14, 7, 12}, {11, 7, 6, 
  16}, {17, 13, 1, 9}, {21, 1, 1, 17}, {5, 18, 4, 13}, {7, 4, 12, 
  17}, {5, 28, 7, 0}, {10, 5, 16, 9}, {4, 24, 10, 2}, {17, 19, 0, 
  4}, {12, 5, 17, 6}, {5, 2, 23, 10}, {16, 4, 9, 11}, {8, 15, 1, 
  16}, {18, 2, 13, 7}, {21, 8, 0, 11}, {2, 31, 7, 0}, {4, 13, 21, 2}} *)
```

Comment: Great work! Thanks a lot! It is the genuine correct answer. With V.E.'s answer, you get a normal distribution for the integer variable(with medium value around 10, I did not see one value over 20 after 1000 samplings). But it may be very useful for other cases.

Comment: I agree with your first comment. I am wrong about the uniform distribution. My goals are indeed contradictory. Your answer is still what I really want.

Comment: I am still wondering. If I sample each of the integer variable randomly between [0,40] for 10^7 times, then I throw away the samples that not satisfying constant sum of 40. Will what have left have similar distribution as yours?

Comment: That looks to be correct. But it's not the fastest way to go about generating examples.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I really "moving fences" or the "fence dance" +1 :)

Answer (score 12):

The [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) is an option:

```
sampleSize = 1;
n = 40;
p = {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4};
RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[n, p], sampleSize]
```

Out (for example):

```
{{14, 11, 10, 5}}
```

Explanation:

n is the number of layers. p contains the probabilities of each type of rock. The Multinomial distribution selects one type of rock n times, according to the probabilities in p.

EDIT:
It's unclear to me what distribution you're looking for. Lichtblau's suggestion may well prove to be more "uniform". Here's another option:

```
f[x_] := If[x > 0, 
   x - RandomVariate[BetaBinomialDistribution[1, 1, x]], 0];
dataBeta = 
  RandomSample@Append[Abs@Differences@#, Last@#] & /@ 
   Table[NestList[f, 40, 3], 1000];
```

The good thing here is that you can play around with the alpha and beta parameters (now both set to 1) to change the distribution. The bad thing is that it's slow.

Comment: That's a very nice approach! (+1)

Comment: Sorry, now I realized my goals are contradictory. If I sample each of the integer variable randomly between [0,40] for 10^7 times, then I throw away the samples that not satisfying constant sum of 40. The type of distribution of what left is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my study of various approaches to generating these tuples.

Tl;dr: all the code can be easily copy-pasted into a new notebook by running this line:

```
NotebookPut@
 ImportString[
  Uncompress@
   FromCharacterCode@
    Flatten@ImageData[Import["http://i.imgur.com/mGkmbGm.png"], 
      "Byte"], "NB"]
```

First I deal with summing *three* integers up to *ten*. This is easier to visualize.

Option 1: Generate *all* 3-tuples with integer components between 0 and 10, then select those, that add up to 10:

```
alltuples = Tuples[{Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10]}];
sum10 = Select[alltuples, Total@# == 10 &];
dist = Tally /@ (Transpose@sum10);
plot = Row[{Graphics3D[Point@alltuples, ImageSize -> 300], 
    Graphics3D[Point@sum10, ImageSize -> 300], 
    ListPlot[dist, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

> [image: One]

From left to right - points representing a 3-tuple (x, y, z), points representing those tuples that add to 10, the frequencies of occurrence of each integer between 0 and 10 for each component of the tuples.

Option 2: Generate a very large amount of random 3-tuples and select the right ones.

```
alltuples = RandomChoice[Range[0, 10], {1000000, 3}];
sum10 = Select[alltuples, Total@# == 10 &];
dist = Tally /@ (Transpose@sum10);
weightall = Tally@alltuples;
weight10 = Tally@sum10;
plot = Row[{Graphics3D[Sphere[#1, #2/2000] & @@@ weightall, 
     ImageSize -> 300], 
    Graphics3D[Sphere[#1, #2/2000] & @@@ weight10, ImageSize -> 300], 
    ListPlot[dist, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

> [image: Two]

Images represent the same as before, but the radii of spheres correspond to the relative frequencies of the occurrence of each tuple. This was the distribution initially desired by OP and, as one can see, the frequencies of each tuple (with and without the restriction of the sum) are more or less the same.

Option 3: Generate tuples by the method in the duplicate question. In other words, generate a bunch of 2-tuples, select those that add up to ten or less and supplement them with a third component that will bring the total up to ten.

```
trunc10 = 
  Select[RandomChoice[Range[0, 10], {10^5, 2}], Total@# <= 10 &];
sum10 = Append[#, 10 - Total@#] & /@ trunc10;
dist = Tally /@ (Transpose@sum10);
weight10 = Tally@sum10;
plot = Row[{Graphics3D[Sphere[#1, #2/2000] & @@@ weight10, 
     ImageSize -> 400], ListPlot[dist, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

> [image: Three]

Here the distribution of tuples that interest us is again uniform. The likelyhood of seeing `n1 = 0, 1, 2, ... 10` is the same as for the previous methods.

Option 4: Daniel's method.

```
sample = Compile[{{total, _Integer}, {len, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   Table[With[{blocks = 
       Join[{0}, 
        Sort[RandomSample[Range[total + len - 1], len - 1]], {total + 
          len}]}, Differences[blocks] - 1], n], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
sum10 = sample[10, 3, 10^5];
dist = Tally /@ (Transpose@sum10);
weight10 = Tally@sum10;
plot = Row[{Graphics3D[Sphere[#1, #2/3000] & @@@ weight10, 
     ImageSize -> 400], ListPlot[dist, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

> [image: Four]

Yields the same result as before.

Option 5: The geological layers approach - three types of soil with equal likelihood of appearance. Select 10 layers from this set of 3 and count how often each type of soil occurs in a given sample.

```
layers = Join[#, {"Type1", "Type2", "Type3"}] & /@ 
   RandomChoice[{"Type1", "Type2", "Type3"}, {10^5, 10}];
bytype = SortBy[First] /@ (Tally /@ layers); bytype = 
 Map[{First@#, Last@# - 1} &, bytype, {2}];
sum10 = Map[Last, bytype, {2}];
dist = Tally /@ (Transpose@sum10);
weight10 = Tally@sum10;
plot = Row[{ArrayPlot[layers[[1 ;; 160, 1 ;; 10]], 
     ColorRules -> {"Type1" -> Red, "Type2" -> Blue, 
       "Type3" -> Yellow}, AspectRatio -> 2, ImageSize -> {200, 400}],
     Graphics3D[Sphere[#1, #2/10000] & @@@ weight10, 
     ImageSize -> 300], ListPlot[dist, ImageSize -> 300]}];
```

> [image: Five]

The array plot is a direct visualization of these soil samples. One can clearly see a considerable difference in the distribution of tuples and counts of each soil type, as compared to the previous approaches.

It is getting late here and I leave it to the curious reader to explore the code for the 4-tuple case (accessible through the `NotebookPut` command at the start of the post). I'll supplement this answer with a look at 4-tuples tomorrow.

A tentative conclusion is that both Daniel's approach, as well as Praan's method from the linked duplicate question/answers seem to yield exactly the same distributions. Both, in turn, match the case of generating a very large number of tuples and selecting only those, that add up to a constant.

**UPDATE:** 4D-case, sum up to 40. I'll omit most of the code here, as it's analogous to the 3D-case. One can access it through the already mentioned `NotebookPut` command at the top of the post.

This problem is still small enough to be bruteforceable, so option 1: all possible tuples.

> [image: Six]

This time the distribution (of frequency of occurrence of each integer) is not linear. If every combination is to have an equal chance of appearance, this is "the" distribution to reference.

Option 2: as before, generate a large amount of 4-tuples, select those that add to 40.

To visualize, I select some of the tuples, and parse them like so:

```
RandomSample[
  Join @@ MapThread[
    ConstantArray[#1, #2] &, {{"Type1", "Type2", "Type3", 
      "Type4"}, #}]] & {11, 4, 15, 10}
```

this will yield a list of length 40 with 11 elements `"Type1"`, 4 of `"Type2"` and so on. A list of these lists is shown in an `ArrayPlot`, once with the elements sorted, once with a random permutation of them.

```
layerview = 
  RandomSample[
     Join @@ MapThread[
       ConstantArray[#1, #2] &, {{"Type1", "Type2", "Type3", 
         "Type4"}, #}]] & /@ sum40;
plot = Row[{ArrayPlot[layerview[[1 ;; 160, 1 ;; 40]], 
     ColorRules -> {"Type1" -> Red, "Type2" -> Blue, 
       "Type3" -> Yellow, "Type4" -> Gray}, AspectRatio -> 2, 
     ImageSize -> {200, 400}],
    ArrayPlot[Sort /@ layerview[[1 ;; 160, 1 ;; 40]], 
     ColorRules -> {"Type1" -> Red, "Type2" -> Blue, 
       "Type3" -> Yellow, "Type4" -> Gray}, AspectRatio -> 2, 
     ImageSize -> {200, 400}],
    ListPlot[dist, ImageSize -> 400]}];
```

`sum40` is of course a list of 4-tuples that add up to 40. The result of the code above is

> [image: Seven]

Pretty much the same results shows up for the rest of the methods. The exception is the `RandomChoice[{"Type1", "Type2", "Type3", "Type4"}, 40]` approach (option 5). The distribution it yields is, of course, considerably different.

> [image: Eight]

IMO, the "randomness" of the distribution of different soil types (pixels of different colors) in this example is much better. On the other hand, when the layers are sorted into groups of one type, one can see a sustained pattern throughout the set of random samples. It is, of course, reflected in the distribution of frequencies of occurrence of integers between 0 and 40. This distribution is now normal.

Comment: Scrolling that last graphic does funky things to my eyes. Not just the vertical movement but, on my machine at least, the rendering changes a bit during scrolling. Gives the effect of a blinking Mondrian.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I agree, it's a terrible sight

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
ranf[sum_, n_, num_] := 
 With[{r = 
    Join @@ (Permutations /@ PadLeft[IntegerPartitions[sum, n]])},
  RandomChoice[r, num]]
```

For example showing relationship to `MultinomialDistribution`:

```
EstimatedDistribution[ranf[40, 4, 1000000], 
 MultinomialDistribution[40, {a, b, c, d}]]
```

yields: `MultinomialDistribution[40, {0.249981, 0.249976, 0.250089, 0.249954}]`