# How to generate a Markov Matrix efficiently

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

A Markov Matrix is a square matrix,which have two features:

- All elements great than or equal to $0$(But I hope all element great than or equal to $0.1$)
- All the columns add up to $1$

I have a custom function for this

```
MarkovMatrix[dim_] := 
 Module[{m}, Label[start]; 
  m = Transpose[
    Append[#, 1 - Total[#]] & /@ 
     RandomReal[1, {dim, dim - 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 2]]; 
  If[AllTrue[m, # > .1 &, 2], m, Goto[start]]; m]
```

## Usage:

For example to generate a 4*4 matrix

```
MatrixForm[m = MarkovMatrix[4]]
```

[image]

But my `MarkovMatrix` is low efficiency function.Are there any better method can do this?

Comment: Surely you mean the columns add up to $1$

Comment: `Transpose[Normalize[#, Total] & /@ RandomReal[1, {4, 4}]]`? Anyway: the more common term is *stochastic matrix*.

Comment: @Feyre OMG.I make a typo.Thanks for your reminder.

Comment: @J.M. I have to say this is a beautiful solution.It deserve a answer but a comment.Another extra my request can you make all element great than or equal to $0.1$ with same elegant method? (Thanks for your term. :)

Comment: relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69707/random-real-numbers-that-sum-up-to-specific-value and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33652/2079.   And for heavens sake never use `Goto`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's something even more compact than my proposal in the comments:

```
Standardize[RandomReal[1, {4, 4}], 0 &, Total]
```

If you must have a left stochastic matrix where all the entries should be greater than a set value, you can do *rejection sampling*: keep generating a matrix as long as the smallest value is smaller than the cutoff:

```
While[Min[sm = Standardize[RandomReal[1, {4, 4}], 0 &, Total]] < 0.1]; sm
```

---

If a **doubly** stochastic matrix is desired (that is, all columns and all rows sum to unity), some more trickery is necessary:

```
While[Min[dsm = FixedPoint[Standardize[Transpose[Standardize[#, 0 &, Total]],
                                       0 &, Total] &, RandomReal[1, {4, 4}],
                           SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - Transpose[#2], "Frobenius"] <
                                        1.*^-12 &)]] < 0.1]; dsm
```

I make no guarantees on the distribution followed by the matrices generated by either method.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want uniformly distributed n-dimensional probability vectors with a minimum value, I think you can use:

```
MarkovMatrix[n_, min_:0] := If[min n<1,
    Transpose @ RandomPoint[Simplex[IdentityMatrix[n](1-min n)], n] + min,
    $Failed
]
```

For example:

```
MarkovMatrix[4, .1] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0.378616 & 0.267013 & 0.416824 & 0.142604 \\
>  0.14229 & 0.305494 & 0.177654 & 0.203273 \\
>  0.231628 & 0.175853 & 0.154734 & 0.178135 \\
>  0.247466 & 0.251641 & 0.250788 & 0.475988 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: For earlier versions that do not have `RandomPoint[]`, here is some equivalent code: `MarkovMatrix[n_, min_: 0] := If[min n < 1, Transpose[((1 - min n) Append[#, 1 - Total[#]]) & /@ RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[ConstantArray[1, n]], n]] + min, $Failed]`

Comment: Just discovered the //TeXForm command. I cried, for real.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my idea

```
make[n_] := ConstantArray[0.1, {n, n}] + (
                 (1 - 0.1 n) #/Total[#, {2}] &[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}]])
```

Because of the minimum you specified for each entry, this works for $n<11$ only. Did you consider letting the minimum value dependent on $n$ in a decreasing manner?

Comment: Thanks for your solution.And I have no that thinking,I just don't hope the element too tiny,which will make some troubles for my processing in following.