# Creating a fast random array generator

Tags: performance-tuning, random

I want to create N x N array of random numbers. (N is an integer).
The constraints are, each element should be between 0 to l(integer) ( here 0<= l <= N) and the sum of elements in each row should be less than equal to N
All elements are integers.

I have to call this  random array generator function many times ( e.g. 10^6 ) and thus this has to be fast.

I wrote the code with procedural programming (very slow), but looking for a way to write it without loops.

For e.g. N=10, l=8, I want to generate 10x10 array with each element between 0 to 8 such that each row sums up to 10. I want to generate this array a million times.

My Code:

```
Nport = 10;
l = 8;
y = {};
While[True,
  x = RandomChoice[Range[0, l], {10^5, Nport}];
 AppendTo[y, Select[x, Total[#] <= Nport &]];
  If [Length[y] >= Nport, Break[]]
 ] // AbsoluteTiming
Take[Flatten[y, 1], Nport]
```

Please Help

I am using Mathematica 9

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of: [(54448)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54448/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, at first I though so too, but this one seems to have an additional constraint on the values (0<=x<=l) which is not in 54448.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to just scrap my previous answer and hopefully this will actually work to include your parameter `l`, which I'm writing `L` to avoid confusion (whereas your `N` is `n` to avoid syntax errors).

```
MyNorm[v_] := n v/Total[v]

MakeRow[] := Block[{v},
 v = MyNorm[RandomReal[1, {n}]];
 While[Max[v] > L, v = MyNorm[RandomReal[1, {n}]]];
 v
];

MakeArray[] := Table[MakeRow[], {n}]

n = 50; L = 5;
Timing[For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++, MakeArray[]]][[1]]/100
(* Output: 0.00062400 *)
```

So for $n=50$ and $l=5$, we can get these cooked up relatively quickly, so that $10^6$ of them will take 10 minutes. Notice that $l$ being close to 1 is a serious problem, so making $l$ smaller will definitely make this worse (in terms of speed):

```
n = 50; L = 1.6;
Timing[For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++, MakeArray[]]][[1]]/100
(* Output: 0.21372137 *)
```

We can test this out to make sure it works:

```
Total /@ MakeArray[]
(* Output: {50., 50., .... , 50.}

Max /@ MakeArray[]
(* Output: {1.58351, 1.54753, 1.57146, .... , 1.59688}
```

However, if $l\sim N$, there shouldn't be much of a slowdown. For example:

```
n = 1000; L = 100;
Timing[For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++, MakeArray[]]][[1]]/100
(* Output: 0.02948419 *)
```

According to my tests, this is as fast as David's answer, but of course includes the parameter `L`. Generally if `L` is not too small, this should be as fast as David's, I think.

This means that, on my PC anyway, you'll get 10^6 of these (when $n=1000$ and $L$ is not too small) over the course of a couple days. Not great, but not infeasible if this is a serious project that's going to be using that large a timescale. On the other hand, $1000\times 1000$ is quite big.. no idea if you want them that big.

Any input for us on exactly how big $n$ is going to be? What is the timeframe you are thinking about? What else is taking up computing time in your algorithm? If it's really $n=10$ and $L=8$, then you can generate $10^6$ of these in a minute or two.

**EDIT FOR INTEGER VALUES**

If you want integers in these arrays, the question is substantially different. I don't think you're going to get much faster than this:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
n = 32; L = 20;
MakeRow[] := Block[{v = RandomComposition[n, n]},
  While[Max[v] > L,
   v = RandomComposition[n, n]
   ];
  v
  ]
MakeArray[] := Table[MakeRow[], {n}]

10^3 Timing[For[i = 1, i <= 10^3, i++, MakeArray[]]][[1]]
```

The output there indicates that generating $10^6$ of these will take about 45 minutes. I don't think you can beat `RandomComposition`, and I doubt even more strongly that you could bring this down to the efficiency of the non-integer version. Maybe this 45 minutes isn't best, but it's not going to be remotely close to 5 minutes (or 1 minute) without a very clever implementation.

Comment: This method is very fast. Thank you. But I am looking for l integer. Check the code attached in my edited question.

Comment: How is that a problem? Just because I used $L=1.6$ (as well as several integer values of $L$ like $8$ and $100$) doesn't mean the code will somehow fail if you never use non-integers. This code works just fine for all integer values of $L$... it just happens to work for any other value of $L$ too.

Comment: I will be happy if I can generate 10^6 in a minute for this particular configuration : n = 32 and l= 20 to 30 . Each element of the matrix has to be an integer.

Comment: **"Each element of the matrix has to be an integer."** You're kidding right? You didn't say that at all. That makes this a completely different question.

Comment: Sorry, Just realized that. I said l is an integer , but that doesn't imply that all elements will be integers.

Comment: Right, and if $L$ is an integer, this code works. If $L$ is not an integer, this code also works. $L$ is just a bound on the entries of the array. Who cares whether it's an integer? It's all the same if you just enforce $a_{i,j}\le L$.

Comment: And for the record, this code generates $10^6$ arrays with $N=32$ and $L=20$ in 5 minutes. I'm going to shrug and say that's about as close as I'm going to get.

Comment: Kellen, It is pretty impressive. The elements of the array are supposed to be number of requests and as in total there are only n channels, sum of rows should be n( or less). Next time Ill frame the question better and give some sample outputs.Thanks

Comment: Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Since there was a request for loop-less solution: `Array[Block[{v = RandomComposition[n, n]}, If[Max@v > L, #0[], v]]&, {10^3, n}]` It is also slightly faster on my machine; v8.0.1

Comment: @KellenMyers did u receive any compatibility message from Needs combinatorica. Though the code runs fine on my machine, I get compatibility warning on first run.Using Mathematica version 9

Comment: That warning is irrelevant. The `Combinatorica` package includes some graph theory functions that have been deprecated in favor of some newer features that don't require loading any packages.

Answer (score 1):

A stylistic suggestion:  Never use the variable $N$, which is a function in *Mathematica* that gives the real value of an expression.

```
n = 10^3;
ii = 174;
n (#/Total[#] & /@ Table[Min[RandomReal[],ii/n], {n}, {n}])
```

This should be fast enough:

```
n = 10^3;
Timing[n (#/Total[#] & /@ Table[Min[RandomReal[],ii/n], {n}, {n}]);]
```

(* {0.451378, Null} *)

Comment: But you'd need to normalize with respect to the sum of elements, i.e. `Normalize[#, Total[#]&/n]&`  or something like that.  This still doesn't guarantee that all numbers are less than `l`, though that is weird constraint and I'm not sure the OP thought it through.  Also, you could use `RandomReal[1, {n,n}]` for brevity and performance.

Comment: Okay, +1 now :-)

Comment: Any thoughts on the parameter `l`?

Comment: Incorporated now.

Answer (score 1):

**I have scrapped this answer -- please consider my other answer instead. I'm leaving this here for reference.**

You should simply use Mathematica's built-in random number generator. For example:

```
n = 50;
f[] := (n /Plus @@ #) # & /@ & /@ Table[Random[], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
```

This function (with no argument) `f[]` will return such a matrix. For `n=50`, we can test the timing.

```
Timing[For[i = 1, i <= 10^4, i++, f[]]][[1]]/10^4
(* Output: 0.0013197685 *)
```

The average instance of $f[]$ for me takes about 0.0013s. So at scale, if you had $10^6$ of these and $n=50$, it's somewhat feasible (about 21 minutes total to generate them all).

It might be useful to know what your `n` (or `N`) value is. If `n=5`, this is a much different question than `n=1000`, in terms of how practically we can produce $10^6$ of these $n\times n$ arrays.

I think both of the answers here have still misconstrued your use of `l` however. I will be updating this answer if I can incorporate that constraint into this.

(Edited due to misreading the question.)

Comment: This will not guarantee that "elements in each row add to N."

Comment: I clearly read the question too quickly!

Comment: And not to be rude, but neither does yours!

Comment: Yep.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what distribution is desired. Here is one that chooses uniformly among all distinction permutations of partitions of all integers `m <= n` into nonnegative parts no greater than `k`.  This is done by transposing the Young tableaux for partitions of `2n` into at most `k + 1` parts, and subtracting `1` to get the parts to be between `0` and `k`.  We then have to select those whose sums are at most `n`.

```
ClearAll[getparts, weights];
mem : getparts[n_, k_] := mem = getpartsC[
    PadRight[IntegerPartitions[2 n, k + 1], {Automatic, k + 1}],
    n];
getpartsC = Compile[{{partitions, _Integer, 2}, {n, _Integer}},
   Select[
    Function[p, Total@Transpose[UnitStep[p - #] & /@ Range[n]] - 1] /@ partitions,
    Last[#] >= 0 &]
   ];
mem : weights[n_, k_] := mem = Multinomial @@@ (Tally /@ getparts[n, k])[[All, All, 2]];
randsamp = Function[{n, howmany}, Ordering /@ RandomReal[1, {howmany, n}]];

ClearAll[nparts];
nparts[n_, k_, nsamp_] :=
  With[{parts = getparts[n, k]},
   With[{p = RandomChoice[weights[n, k] -> parts, nsamp]},
    Compile[{{pp, _Integer, 2}, {samp, _Integer, 2}},
      MapThread[#1[[#2]] &, {pp, samp}]][p, randsamp[n, nsamp]]
    ]];
```

A one-time cost: computing the basic partitions:

```
getparts[32, 20] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {32.0588, {43202, 32}}  *)
```

Generating samples is fairly quick (it seems to be an order of magnitude faster than the `` Combinatorica` `` code of [Kellen Meyers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9482/kellen-myers), although there is a claim in a comment, without supporting code, that suggests it might be about the same).  A million samples should take a total of about six minutes.

```
Table[nparts[32, 20, 32], {10^3}] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.35359, {1000, 32, 32}}  *)
```

Getting them in chunks is faster, if you have the memory.  A thousand 32x32 arrays is not much, but a million takes more memory than I have RAM, and therefore would be much slower to do all at once.

```
ArrayReshape[
   nparts[32, 20, 32*10^3],
   {10^3, 32, 32}] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.070147, {1000, 32, 32}}  *)
```

---

Comparison of this approach and the `` Combinatorica` `` approach (`MakeArray`):

```
10^3 AbsoluteTiming[Do[MakeArray[], {10^3}]]
10^3 AbsoluteTiming[Do[nparts[32, 20, 32], {10^3}]]
10^3 AbsoluteTiming[ArrayReshape[nparts[32, 20, 32*10^3], {10^3, 32, 32}];]
(*
  {3146.06, 1000 Null}
  {357.585, 1000 Null}
  {78.877, 1000 Null}
*)
```

Note that you need to add 30 sec. to the `nparts` results for the one-time computation of the basic partitions.