# Difficulty in parallelizing function using package (MCMC)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, parallelization, estimation

### Difficulty in parallelizing Packages using `DistributeDefinitions`

**Context**

I am trying to parallelize some parameter estimation using MCMC.

As a test run I expect it to find the width of a Gaussian.

If I use the built in Mathematica function `FindDistributionParameters`, it parallelizes nicely:

```
Table[x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2/10], 50000]; 
  FindDistributionParameters[x, NormalDistribution[0, s]], {i, 
   40}] // Timing
```

{0.324758, {{s -> 0.200035},…}

runs much slower than

```
ParallelTable[x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2/10], 50000]; 
  FindDistributionParameters[x, NormalDistribution[0, s]], {i, 
   40}] // Timing
```

{0.016444, {{s -> 0.199899}, …}

If I now use a [MCMC](https://github.com/joshburkart/mathematica-mcmc/blob/master/mcmc.m) package (following this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137636/1089))

```
<<MCMC.m

Unprotect[Monitor];
Monitor = # &;
Protect[Monitor];
DistributeDefinitions[MCMC];
```

For some reason this (non parallel) implementation is as slow

```
Table[x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2/10], 500]; 
  f[s_] = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[0, s], x]; 
  MCMC[f[s], {{s, 0.1, 0.4, Reals}}, 1000]["BestFitParameters"]
  , {i, 4}] // Timing
```

{2.26298,{{s->0.188522},{s->0.208759},{s->0.208809},{s->0.1983}}

as that (parallel) implementation:

```
ParallelTable[x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2/10], 500]; 
  f[s_] = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[0, s], x]; 
  MCMC[f[s], {{s, 0.1, 0.4, Reals}}, 1000]["BestFitParameters"]
  , {i, 4}] // Timing
```

{3.38599,{{s->0.199691},{s->0.200183},{s->0.206191},{s->0.201176}}

### Question

> Why does `ParallelTable` not scale up on this problem given that the different jobs are fully independent?

PS: note that an alternative option could involve parallelizing the function itself, following e.g. this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143668/1089)

Comment: I recently found that in using packages I would need to use `Needs[]` as well as `ParallelNeeds[]` to have the definitions distributed correctly to the Kernels.

Comment: Suprised the heck out of me, too... just when one thought, one knew all the tricks. :)

Comment: When I do this with MCMC, I get `Min::nord` and `FrontEndObject::notavail` (albeit getting the correct result). Do you get the same messages?

Comment: @gwr yes unless I do ParallelDo[Unprotect[Monitor]; Monitor = # &; Protect[Monitor]; , {4}]; because the function uses Monitor.

Comment: I'm not an expert but "parallel" and "random numbers" ring some bells. I think there are some peculiarities with that combination. If unsure you might want to make sure that what you do is correct...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Loading Packages with [`ParallelNeeds`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelNeeds.html)

As Szabolcs has nicely posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73384/764) distributing definitions to the Kernels by using [`DistributeDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html) like so:

```
DistributeDefinitions[ "PackageContext`"]
```

will not work. Since definitions of the default context are distributed automatically, one needs to make sure, that packages loaded via [`Needs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Needs.html) also "reach" the Kernels.

This can be achieved by using [`ParallelNeeds`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelNeeds.html). But one still needs to load the package into the global context thus in your case:

```
Needs[ "MCMC`"];
ParallelNeeds[ "MCMC`"];
```

That should do the trick.

In practice for the problem at hand:

```
ParallelDo[Unprotect[Monitor];Monitor = # &; Protect[Monitor];, {4}]
```

Then we can compute best estimate and error on estimate as follow:

```
res = ParallelTable[
   x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2/10], 5000]; 
   f[m_, s_] = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[m, s], x]; 
   MCMC[f[m, s], {{m, 0.1, 0.01, Reals},
      {s, 0.1, 0.01, Reals}}, 5000][{"BestFitParameters", 
     "ParameterErrors"}]
   , {i, 32*8}];

dat = Join[{m, s} /. Map[#[[1, 2]] &, res] // 
     Transpose, {m, s} /. Map[#[[2, 2]] &, res] // Transpose] // 
   Transpose;
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
ErrorListPlot[{{#1, #2}, ErrorBarPlots`ErrorBar @@ {#3, #4}} & @@@ 
  dat, PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.15], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Indeed the Maximum likelihood method is unbiased

```
 dat1 = {m, s} /. Map[#[[1, 2]] &, res]; dat1 // DensityHistogram
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]