# How can I use FeynCalc in ParallelTable or ParallelSum?

Tags: parallelization, contexts, feyncalc

I want to speed up a [FeynCalc](https://feyncalc.github.io/) calculation. However I found out that it doesn't seem to work in `ParallelSum` or `ParallelTable`.

MWE:

```
<<FeynCalc`

ParallelTable[
 With[
  {exp = DiracTrace[GA[\[Mu]] . GA[\[Nu]], 
     DiracTraceEvaluate -> True]},
  Print[exp]
  ], {i, 1, 4}, DistributedContexts -> "FeynCalc`"
 ]
```

Expected Output:

```
4 Pair[LorentzIndex[\[Mu]], LorentzIndex[\[Nu]]
4 Pair[LorentzIndex[\[Mu]], LorentzIndex[\[Nu]]
4 Pair[LorentzIndex[\[Mu]], LorentzIndex[\[Nu]]
4 Pair[LorentzIndex[\[Mu]], LorentzIndex[\[Nu]]
```

Actual Output:

```
FeynCalc`DiracTrace[FeynCalc`GA[\[Mu]].FeynCalc`GA[\[Nu]],FeynCalc`DiracTraceEvaluate->T
FeynCalc`DiracTrace[FeynCalc`GA[\[Mu]].FeynCalc`GA[\[Nu]],FeynCalc`DiracTraceEvaluate->T
FeynCalc`DiracTrace[FeynCalc`GA[\[Mu]].FeynCalc`GA[\[Nu]],FeynCalc`DiracTraceEvaluate->T
FeynCalc`DiracTrace[FeynCalc`GA[\[Mu]].FeynCalc`GA[\[Nu]],FeynCalc`DiracTraceEvaluate->T
```

To me this looks like the Context is not recognized. I thought I accomodated this with `DistributedContexts->"FeynCalc`" but apparently this does not work.

How can I get this running?

I also tried `DistributedContexts->Automatic` but got the same result.

Comment: I don't have this package, but what happens if you just say "DistributedContexts->Automatic"?

Comment: @HansOlo same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it for the heck of it and it worked.

One has to load FeynCalc` in each Kernel.

```
ParallelTable[<<FeynCalc`;,{i,1,4}] (* execute once *)
```

Now we dont even have to distribute any context

```
ParallelTable[
 With[
  {exp = DiracTrace[GA[\[Mu]] . GA[\[Nu]], 
     DiracTraceEvaluate -> True]},
  Print[exp]
  ], {i, 1, 4}
 ]
```

Comment: I searched "parallel package" here on stack exchange and found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139152/86543) which might answer your question. I did not read everything but the answer uses `ParallelNeeds` which your parallel table might be reproducing to some degree. It might be safer/better to use `ParallelNeeds`, not sure.