# Generate two random numbers with constraints

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, regions

I want to generate two random numbers, $p$ and $q$, between $0.5$ and $1$.

They are connected by the constraint $1/(2q) > p$.

How do I generate $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Come on people, if an answer was worth 6 upvotes, surely the question must be worth a few too, no matter how trivial. Many did learn right here about RandomPoint, no?

Comment: @Szabolcs http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal :D

Comment: To add to the comment by @Szabolcs, this question is far from trivial.

Comment: This is relevant here too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: I think a much more interesting question would be to find points $(p,q)$ obeying the constraint but that $P(p) \sim {\cal U}[.5, 1]$ and $P(q) \sim {\cal U}[.5, 1]$, which none of these solutions ensure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you just ommitted the parentheses and meant $1/(2q) > p$, then this works

```
q = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}]
p = RandomReal[{0.5, 1/(2 q)}]
```

Edit:  The above code will generate 2 random numbers that satisfy the given criteria, they won't be sampling the same distribution.

```
qlist = RandomReal[{0.5, 1.0}, 10000];
plist = RandomReal[{0.5, 1/(2 #)}] & /@ qlist; 
ListPlot[ Transpose[{qlist, plist}]]
```

[image]

You see that the first variable samples `{0.5,1.0}` uniformly while the other does not.  But the inequality is symmetric, and can be written $1/(2p)>q$ so that isn't right.  rhermans's answer fixes this, but it runs unreasonably slow on my machine.  For example, generating a list of 1000 pairs takes about 100 seconds for me using `ImplicitRegion` and `RandomPoint`.

But I can do it in about a tenth of a second using this inelegant code

```
list2 = Reap[
     i = 0;
     While[
      i < 10001,
      test = RandomReal[{0.5, 1.0}, 2];
      If[test[[1]] < 1/(test[[2]] 2), i++; Sow[test]];
      ]
     ][[2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListPlot@list2
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried that one. Its working for one single random number. But If I want to produce say 100 numbers then its not working.

Comment: in what way is it not working?

Comment: @ChandanDatta `qs = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 100];ps = RandomReal[{0.5, 1/(2 #)}] & /@ qs;`

Comment: And then just to verify the results: `(0.5 < #1 < 1.0 && 0.5 < #2 < 1.0 && #2 < 1/(2 #1)) & @@@ Transpose[{qs, ps}]`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Now Its working fine.

Answer (score 35):

> This assumes uniform distribution. See answer by @JimBaldwin for discussion on limitations (implicit assumptions) of my answer.

### Answer

```
region = ImplicitRegion[0.5 < q < 1. && 0.5 < p < 0.5/q, {p, q}];
RandomPoint[region]
(* {0.793318, 0.550934} *)
```

---

### Visual

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[region]
 , ListPlot[RandomPoint[region, 1000], PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Documentation

We are using [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And  [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @rhermans neat and thank you for introducing me to RandomPoint +1 :)

Comment: Is this unreasonably slow for anyone else?  When I evaluate `list = Table[RandomPoint[region], {1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming` it takes about 100 seconds

Comment: That does seem like a bug, I'm using linux version 10.2

Comment: The overhead is mainly the symbolic computations, numerical approximation reduces it significantly. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97442/10397)

Answer (score 28):

The question does not state an essential piece of information which is the joint distribution of $p$ and $q$. All of the previous answers (so far) jump to a solution without making the joint distribution explicit (at least prior to what one sees in the code and the resulting figures).

The answers using regions assume that $p$ and $q$ have uniform distributions, $U(0.5,1)$, but they are restricted to the region $0.5 \le p \le 1$, $0.5 \le q \le 1$, and ${1\over{2q}}>p$.

The other answer given is that $p\sim U(0.5,1)$ and $q|p\sim U(0.5,{1\over{2p}}))$.

There is no reason why one couldn't have $p\sim 0.5+0.5\,\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ with $q|p\sim U(0.5,{1\over{2p}})$. A random sample from a linear function of a beta random variable is also a legitimate random sample.

The question most likely is about restricting two independent random variables from uniform distributions to a region, but that should be made explicit.

**Addition:  Doing it the hard way**

Using regions and `RandomPoint` is the way to go as @rhermans describes (especially if the region of interest is not simple).  But if you want to go about it in a brute force way, here is an option.

First we assume that without the additional restrictions that $p$ and $q$ are independently distributed on $U(0.5,1)$.  The joint probability density function in the square of interest is

```
f[p_, q_] := 4
```

Now determine the joint probability density when $0.5\le p<1/(2q)\le 1$:

```
c = Integrate[f[p, q], {q, 1/2, 1}, {p, 1/2, 1/(2 q)}];
g[p_, q_] := f[p, q]/c
(* 4/(-1 + Log[4]) *)
```

Find the marginal probability density function for $p$:

```
gp[p_] := FullSimplify[Integrate[g[p, q], {q, 1/2, 1/(2 p)}]]
(* 2(1-p)/(p*(-1+Log[4])) *)
```

Now find the conditional distribution of $q$ given $p$ (which is just a uniform distribution on $0.5$ to $1/(2p)$):

```
gqGivenp[q_, p_] := g[p, q]/gp[p]
(* 2p/(1-p) *)
```

Define a `ProbabilityDistribution` for $p$:

```
dp = ProbabilityDistribution[gp[p], {p, 1/2, 1}];
```

Finally, generate a set of bivariate random samples:

```
n = 5000;  (* Number of samples *)
rp = RandomVariate[dp, n];
rq = 0.5 + RandomReal[1, n]*(1/(2 rp) - 0.5);
```

Plotting the results we have

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{rp, rq}], PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: bivariate sample]

This approach might also be successful when the original joint probability function is a bit more complex.

Comment: +1; people should really get into the habit of thinking about distributions when dealing with random number/point generation problems.

Comment: I agree with you and on this particular subject I have seen quite some ignorance, possibly resulting from a lack of formal language. On the other hand, it appears some people will use the word "random" in isolation to mean uniformly distributed quite consistently.

Comment: Its not that unreasonable to assume uniform distribution as default if no other information is given. Arguably it is the simplest distribution.

Comment: I agree.  But I think any answers should make that assumption explicit.

Comment: @JimBaldwin thank you for this instructive answer +1. :)

Comment: @J.M. & Jim, there is/are more discussion and opinions about this [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54448/random-numbers-that-sum-up-to-specific-value/73169#comment156595_54450) and that Q&A is quite similar.

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps more a comment: note differences:

```
r = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, {10000, 2}];
Show[ListPlot[Sort@GatherBy[r, Times @@ # < 0.5 &], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red}, Blue}], 
 Plot[1/(2 x), {x, 0.5, 1}, PlotStyle -> Green], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

compared with:

```
ListPlot[{#, RandomReal[{0.5, 1/(2 #)}]} & /@ 
  RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 10000], PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Desired outcome depends on aim. Latter understandable given narrowing of uniform distribution of "q" as  "p"->1

Comment: Also campare with `ListPlot[{RandomReal[{0.5, 1/(2 #)}], #} & /@ 
  RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 10000], PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True]`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Yes, if you think I am being unhelpful I am happy to delete...I note 2 down votes so I may have misunderstood something...

Comment: @Karsten7. By yes I mean appreciate the symmetry and perhaps I should have used aspect ratio 1 and amplified point showing dense points on vertical axis...to illustrate what was my point which is care about 'random'

Comment: You had my +1 before I added my comment. In my opinion pointing out the differences between these two approaches is essential.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thank you for the clarification...long day...super sensitive. Appreciate clarification.

Comment: Maybe someone misinterpreted your answer as a copy of the [answer by Jason B](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97425/18476) not seeing that an alternative approach of creating random points is included within your first plot.

Comment: Whoever did the downvote probably just didn't understand your post, and they'd probably take it back if the system let them do so after 17 minutes.  Probably.  That's probably what they'd do

Comment: @JasonB thank you...I am always more afraid that I have made some fundamental mistake that I would not want to perpetuate...embarrassment often ushers improved understanding for me...but I still don't like it :)

Comment: One of my favorite "teaching" moments when teaching computational physics is to ask the students to generate random points in a circle, using polar coordinates; invariably, they uniformly choose the radius of the circle and are confused when the density of points decreases with the radius.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another approach with `RandomVariate` and `ProbabilityDistribution`. First we find the area that can be occupied by points satisfying the criteria:

```
norm = Integrate[Boole[1/(2 y) > x], {x, 1/2, 1}, {y, 1/2, 1}]
(* (Log[4] - 1)/4 *)
```

Let `p` run along the horizontal axis and `q` along the vertical axis.

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[1 > 1/(2 p) > q > 1/2, {p, q}], PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Here's the region of allowed values for `{p,q}`.

[image: region]

equal small elements of area from this region must have equal likelihood of being occupied. The area corresponding to a range $(p, p + dp)$ is then simply $\frac{dp}{2 p} - \frac{dp}{2}$. Dividing by $dp$ we'll get the probability distribution of `p`. We define a distribution:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(1/(2 x) - 1/2)/norm, {x, 1/2, 1}]
```

which must be normalized (`/norm`).

```
Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 2/5, 6/5}]
```

[image: pdf]

Now we generate a list of random `p`s with the above distribution:

```
(p = RandomVariate[dist, 100000]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.211 seconds *)
```

and find a random `q` corresponding to the constraint of each of the random `p`:

```
(q = RandomReal[{.5, 1/(2 #)}] & /@ p) // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* ~ 9 msec *)
```

Then plot every 100th point (not all of them, otherwise it's difficult to assess if it's uniform or not):

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{p, q}][[;; ;; 100]]]
```

[image: points]

This is about 5 times faster than Jason`s`Reap-Sow` approach.

Most likely, better results can be achieved by using a proper combination of built-in distribution functions. Unfortunately, `RandomVariate` refuses to accept multivariate distributions from `ProbabilityDistribution`, which is why there's a generation of first a list of `p`s and then a list of `q`s, instead of directly generating pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way but

```
FindInstance[1/(2 q) > p && 0.5 < p < 1 && 0.5 < q < 1, {p, q}, 100, 
RandomSeed -> RandomInteger[100]]
```