# Huge overhead in RandomPoint[ImplicitRegion]

Tags: performance-tuning, random

Commenting answers of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97424/10397) @JasonB noticed the big overhead of [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html)

```
region = ImplicitRegion[1 > 1/(2 q) > p > 1/2, {p, q}];
First@RepeatedTiming[RandomPoint[region], 1]
```

> ```
> 0.1010
> ```

Compare with

```
First@RepeatedTiming[RandomPoint[Disk[]], 1]
```

> ```
> 0.00019
> ```

Further test for more points ( **Mma 10.3 Win7 64** ):

```
tl = Table[
  {
   2^k,
   First@RepeatedTiming[RandomPoint[region, 2^k], 1]
   }, {k, 24}]
```

Plot

```
ListLogLogPlot[
 tl
 , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
 , FrameLabel -> {"# of Random Points", "RepeatedTiming"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Its ***0.1 seconds overhead*** which seems unreasonable and we suspect a bug.

**Q: Can we find the source of the overhead and a reasonable workaround?**

**EDIT**

```
tl2 = Table[
  {
   2^k,
   First@RepeatedTiming[RandomPoint[Disk[], 2^k], 1]
   }, {k, 25}]

ListLogLogPlot[
 {tl, tl2}
 , Joined -> True
 , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
 , FrameLabel -> {"Number of Random Points", "RepeatedTiming"}
 , PlotLegends -> {"ImplicitRegion", "Disk"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Babbage would be proud

Comment: When you read the label on the first axis as "`Slot` of Random Points" :p

Comment: Somehow I wouldn't expect a low overhead here ... `ImplicitRegion` is a symbolic region.  There must be a lot of symbolic processing going on at the beginning: Is the region bounded? Based on its shape, what method is likely to be fastest for large numbers of points? Then transform the region into the proper form for the method (e.g. is it a rejection method, or direct sampling?)  `Disk` is a predefined region so `RandomPoint` can easily specialize for it.  It probably has a a `RandomPointInDisk` internal generator for it...  But that's not going to work for an implicit region.

Comment: Or am I missing something?  How would you implemented RandomPoint for general implicit regions?  BTW thank you for showing me RepeatedTiming! I was still using my own custom version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by @Szabolcs, "a lot of symbolic processing" is behind when using symbolic representation. Numerical approximation severely reduces the overhead.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
  Evaluate[
   N@Reduce[1 > 1/(2 q) > p > 1/2]
   ], {p, q}]
```

> ```
> ImplicitRegion[0.5 < q < 1. && 0.5 < p < 0.5/q, {p, q}]
> ```

```
First@RepeatedTiming[RandomPoint@reg, 1]
```

> ```
> 0.000687
> ```

```
tl3 = Table[
   {
    2^k,
    First@RepeatedTiming[RandomPoint[reg, 2^k], 1]
    }, {k, 25}];
```

Plot

```
ListLogLogPlot[
 {tl, tl2, tl3}
 , Joined -> False
 , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
 , FrameLabel -> {"Number of Random Points", "RepeatedTiming"}
 , PlotLegends -> {"ImplicitRegion Symbolic", "Disk", 
   "ImplicitRegion Approx"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]