# Uniform distribution on z = 1 − √( x ^2 + y ^2) , z ≥ 0

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

Let $S$ belong to ${\rm I\!R^3}$, $z = 1 − \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ ,   $z ≥ 0$.

I need to write a program that generates a random point on $S$ with uniform distribution. I've tried to use

```
g[z_, fi_] = {(1 - z)*Cos[2 Pi*fi], (1 - z)*Sin[2 Pi*fi], z};
sample[n_] := Table[g[RandomReal[], RandomReal[]], {n}];

sampleX[n_] := Table[g[RandomReal[], RandomReal[]][[1]], {n}];
sampleY[n_] := Table[g[RandomReal[], RandomReal[]][[2]], {n}];
sampleZ[n_] := Table[g[RandomReal[], RandomReal[]][[3]], {n}];
```

But the result isn't exact, because I have more points on the top and less points near $OXY$.

[image]

How could I make a Uniform distribution on this surface?

Comment: One more question :) How to calculate an integral(z dS) using wolfram mathematica?

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Your *"one more question"* can be found in the documentation of [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html). Follow the link.

Comment: w.r.t. t = 1-z, so the cumulative distribution function is t^2. Why is it so?

Answer (score 13):

If you set up your region `S` as a region in *Mathematica* you can use `RandomPoint` to generate uniformly distributed points over it.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   z == 1 - Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)], {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg]
rp = RandomPoint[dreg, 10000];
Show[ContourPlot3D[
  z == 1 - Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.05], Point[rp]}]]
```

[image]

[image]

This should be fine for most purposes, but note that the discretised region `dreg` is a numerical approximation to the `ImplicitRegion`, `reg`. So, for example

```
point = RandomPoint[dreg]
RegionMember[dreg, point]
RegionMember[reg, point]

(* {-0.538245, -0.716972, 0.103292}
   True
   False *)
```

That is, while `point` in the discretised region, `dreg`, it is not *actually* in the implicit region `reg`. Although it is close:

```
RegionDistance[reg, point]

(* 0.000129349 *)
```

The approximation of the mesh in `dreg` could be improved with `MaxCellMeasure`.

In case you're wondering, sadly we can't just generate `RandomPoint`s from `reg`:

```
RandomPoint[reg]

(* RandomPoint[ImplicitRegion[z == 1 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] && -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}]] *)
```

It "should" work (according to documentation), but `Region` functionality in *Mathematica* often has funny quirks to it.

**UPDATE: Comparison of approaches to uniform distributions over a region embedded in a higher dimensional space**

There have been two general approaches to generating uniformly distributed random points over the surface of a cone. @Coolwater and @george2079 opted for analytical solutions, while @Carl Woll and myself used *Mathematica*'s built in `Region` functionality. I wanted to have a look at how these approaches compare in accuracy and speed; and get a sense of how best to approach similar problems.

An important feature of this question is that the region dimension is less than the embedding dimension (and this is the reason for the woeful accuracy of `RandomPoint` applied to `DiscretizeRegion`; if `RegionDimension == EmbeddingDimension` accuracy shouldn't be a problem). With this in mind, the take-home message based on the table below seems to be:

1. Keep to analytical solutions as far as possible. A little math goes a long way.
2. If you must use `Region`s, use the `ParametricRegion` or built-in ones.
3. Use `ImplicitRegion` and `DiscretizeRegion` only in emergencies.

First, a few definitions:

```
carlreg = 
  RegionIntersection[RegionBoundary[Cone[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 2]],
    ConicHullRegion[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}}]];
implicitreg = 
  ImplicitRegion[
    z == 1 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];
discreg = DiscretizeRegion[implicitreg];
parareg = 
  ParametricRegion[{Cos[θ] u, Sin[θ] u, 1 - u}, 
    {{θ, 0, 2 π}, {u, 0, 1}}];

coolwater[n_] := 
 Transpose[{Cos[#] #2, Sin[#] #2, 1 - #2} &[RandomReal[2 π, n], 
   Sqrt[RandomReal[1, n]]]]
george[n_] := 
 Append[#1 Through[{Sin, Cos}@#2], 1 - #1] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[2 r, {r, 0, 1}], 
     n], RandomReal[{0, 2 π}, n]}]
carlwoll[n_] := RandomPoint[carlreg, n]
aardvark[n_] := RandomPoint[discreg, n]
parametric[n_] := RandomPoint[parareg, n]
```

Now generate some points

```
{names, timing, points} = 
  Transpose[Join[{#}, AbsoluteTiming[#[1000]]] & /@ 
    {coolwater, george, carlwoll, aardvark, parametric}];
regdist = Mean[RegionDistance[implicitreg, #]] & /@ points;
solerror = Mean[Abs[#3 - (1 - Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2])] & @@@ #] & /@ points;
TextGrid[Join[{{"", "Timing", "RegionDistance", "Solution error"}}, 
  Transpose[{names, timing, regdist, solerror}]]]
```

\begin{array}{|c|ccc|}
\hline
 \text{} & \text{Timing} & \text{RegionDistance} & \text{Solution error} \\
\hline
 \text{coolwater} & 0.0003290 & 1.25468 \times 10^{-10} &   1.68754 \times 10^{-17} \\
 \text{george} & 0.0049363 & 1.66830 \times 10^{-10} & 1.87628 \times 10^{-17} \\
\hline
 \text{carlwoll} & 0.0458737 & 5.67581 \times 10^{-10} & 6.13953 \times 10^{-17} \\
 \text{aardvark} & 0.0006388 & 0.000600271 & 0.000849862 \\
 \text{parametric} & 0.0251807 & 7.21428 \times 10^{-11} & 1.74305 \times 10^{-17} \\
\hline
\end{array}

A few words about the difference between `implicitreg`, `parareg` and @CarlWoll's `carlreg`. They are clearly the same mathematical region, their `Region`-based properties (`RegionMeasure`, `RegionCentroid`, etc) are identical, and `FindInstance` cannot find any points that they do not all have in common. However, `RandomPoint` can be used directly on `carlreg` and `parareg` but not on `implicitreg`. I don't have an explanation why that is the case, but it is possibly related to [this question by @rhermans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97430/huge-overhead-in-randompointimplicitregion). Basically, `ImplicitRegion`s are much more complicated for *Mathematica* to work with. So using them for a case like this, where there are many other options, is clearly (in hindsight) a mistake.

Comment: I think that problem is here: 
    g[z_, fi_] = {(1 - z)*Cos[2 Pi*fi], (1 - z)*Sin[2 Pi*fi], z};
I didn't use Jacobian to generate the points, but idk how to do that

Comment: Is it real to get the coordinates of these points, which are generated?

Comment: Ahh, ofc! Just there is a list rp

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works

Answer (score 9):

The radius increase linearly w.r.t. `t = 1-z`, so the cumulative distribution function is `t^2`. Hence transforming uniform variables for `t` by the square root (the quantile) makes the result uniform.

```
samp[n_] := Transpose[{Cos[#] #2, Sin[#] #2, 1 - #2} &[
              RandomReal[2 π, n], Sqrt[RandomReal[1, n]]]]

surf = ContourPlot3D[z == 1 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}];
Show[surf, ListPointPlot3D[samp[9000]]]
```

[image]

Comment: w.r.t. t = 1-z, so the cumulative distribution function is t^2.
Why is it so?

Comment: The radius of the circles around the z-axis is `t`. And the radius is proportional to the density of points conditional on `z` (or `t` same-same). The CDF `t^2` is the result of integrating the radius (wrongly scaled density) and scaling to have range 0 to 1.

Comment: Thanks! Understood

Answer (score 5):

Your surface is just the boundary of a cone (excluding the base), and [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint) will work with the region boundary of a [`Cone`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cone) object. We can intersect the region boundary of a slightly extended cone with a region with $z>0$ to eliminate the base. RandomPoint will also work with this region intersection object. So, I will use a cone with a circle of radius 2 at $(0, 0, -1)$ as the base and $(0, 0, 1)$ as the top, so that the intersection with $z>0$ is the desired cone:

```
reg = RegionIntersection[
    RegionBoundary[Cone[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 2]],
    ConicHullRegion[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}}]
];

pts = RandomPoint[reg, 1000];

Graphics3D[{Point@pts, RGBColor[0, 1, 1, .5], Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

And, here is a check that `pts` satisfy the desired equation:

```
Tally @ Chop[Function[{x, y, z}, z - (1 - Sqrt[x^2+y^2])] @@@ pts]
```

> {{0, 1000}}

Answer (score 2):

small tweak using `RandomVariate` :

```
n = 10^3
ListPointPlot3D[
 Append[#1 Through[{Sin,Cos}@#2], 1 - #1] & @@@ 
 Transpose[{
   RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[2 r , {r, 0, 1}], n],
   RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n]}]]
```