# Generate random numbers in such a way that their combinations meet the specified conditions

Tags: random

We need to generate 5 numbers $\alpha,\beta,p,q,k$ so that they meet the following conditions:

1. $\alpha,\beta,p,q,k>0$
2. $k \cdot p <1$
3. $k \cdot q >1$

**Edit:**

I think, that this code may be solution:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[\[Alpha] > 0 && \[Beta] > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0 && k > 0 && k p < 1 && k q > 1, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], p, q, k}];

RandomPoint[region]
```

*But this still very slowly!*

[Generate two random numbers with constraints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97424/generate-two-random-numbers-with-constraints/97434)

Comment: It looks like you can at least generate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ independent of the other three...

Comment: `While[True,{a,b,p,q,k}=RandomReal[{0,2},5];If[k*p<1&&k*q>1,Break[]]];{a,b,p,q,k}` completes almost instantly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify what kinds of distributions you want to consider.  Otherwise there are infinite numbers of possibilities.  Here's one:

```
x = RandomVariate[ChiSquareDistribution[1], {1000, 5}];
{α, β, p, q, k} = Select[x, #[[3]] #[[5]] < 1 && #[[4]] #[[5]] > 1 &][[1]]
(* {0.198549, 0.0376487, 0.0248636, 1.00516, 1.8256} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a uniform distribution, you must specify some upper bound. For an example I choose an upper bound of 1. The lower bound is ">0", but as the probability of choosing zero is zero, we may simply choose the lower bound as zero:

```
While[ {a, b, p, q, k} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5]; k p > 1 || k q > 1]
{a, b, p, q, k}
AllTrue[{k p, k q}, # < 1 &]
```