# Using sublists returned from a function as elements of a list argument to an other function

Tags: list-manipulation

This is a contrived example, but it gets the point across.  I am looking to use the following as inputs:

```
a = {10, 11};
b = {5, 7};
MakeCD[x_] := {{x, 2 x}, {3 x, 4 x}};
```

to function that takes a list of sublists. `ListPlot` is a suitable example of the function.

Using `1` as the argument to `MakeCD`, `MakeCD` returns: `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`

I am looking to supply `{{10, 11}, {5, 7}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}` to `ListPlot`

I can achieve this with the following:

```
{c, d} = MakeCD[1];
{a, b, c, d}
```

Also with:

```
Join[{a}, {b}, MakeCD[1]]
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this, but I have not yet stumbled upon it yet.

Comment: Something like `Flatten[{MakeCD[1], MakeCD[10]}, 1]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks unfortunate contrived example that `MakeCD` can generate a,b,c,d. I changes that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second try:

From the comments I believe you are looking for [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html):

```
{a, b, Sequence @@ MakeCD[1]}
```

> ```
> {{10, 11}, {5, 7}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}
> ```

You can include this in the definition of `MakeCD`, or an auxiliary function, to streamline this:

```
MakeCD2[x_] := Sequence[{x, 2 x}, {3 x, 4 x}];

{a, b, MakeCD2[1]}
```

> ```
> {{10, 11}, {5, 7}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}
> ```

You can also use [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) to perform a similar action:

```
{a, b, ##}& @@ MakeCD[1]
```

> ```
> {{10, 11}, {5, 7}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}
> ```

Or more in line with your application:

```
plotfunction[{a, b, ##}, plotoptions] & @@ MakeCD[1]
```

> ```
> plotfunction[{{10, 11}, {5, 7}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}, plotoptions]
> ```

For an advanced method that will be useful with held expressions see:
[Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937)

Comment: I have a variable number of series of date data to be plotted by DateListPlot. In my example, I have two represented by `a` & `b`.  There could be any number of series of date data (1-5+).  In addition to the series data, I will also always have two additional series of date date that are generated by a function. In my example, that is represented by `MakeCD[]`.  The problem is that any function that returns multiple values, returns a list of the values, in my case series of date data. I was hoping for a way to remove the outer list and just supply the two sublists to `DateListPlot`

Comment: i.e. `DateListPlot[{a,b,x,y,z, Delistify[MakeCD[1]]` Obviously `Delistify[]` does not exist, but the result would have been `DateListPlot[{a,b,x,y,z,{1,2},{3,4}]` And yes that would not have plotted since `{1,2}` should have been  something like `{{{2013, 8, 27}, 42}, {{2013, 8, 28}, 40}}`.  Just trying to save space, but probably cause more confusion.

Comment: @mmorris Oh!  I think you're just looking for `Sequence`.  Update imminent.

Comment: @mmorris Don't miss my addition regarding `SlotSequence` -- it's the method I use most often in cases like this.

Comment: I understand `Sequence`, wrapping my head around `SlotSequence`.  Thanks