# HoldForm and RandomChoice

Tags: random

I'm trying to get random expressions displaying. For that, I'm starting with addition, multiplication, substraction and division. When trying out this code

```
 HoldForm[c e d] /. c -> RandomInteger[{1, 15}] /. 
 d -> RandomInteger[{1, 15}] /. 
 e -> RandomChoice[{"-", "+", "/", "*"}]
```

, I sometimes get indeed expressions as "11 "+" 6" as expected, but I also get

```
 14 "-"
```

or

```
 "-" 9.
```

Why is that?

Perhaps anyone has another idea for making randomised arithmetic expressions?
Thanks, once again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
HoldForm[op@##] & @@ RandomInteger[{1, 15}, 2] /. 
 op -> RandomChoice[{Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! One more question: why doesn't this work:

HoldForm[Plus @@ ##] &@{a, b} ?
Thanks for all information!

Comment: @Gabriel `FullForm` of `a + b` is `Plus[a, b]`, not `Plus@@{a, b}`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a subtly different form of what ybeltukov proposed:

```
RandomChoice[{Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide}] /. op_ :>
    HoldForm[op@##] & @@ RandomInteger[{1, 15}, 2]
```

You'll notice that the rule is used in reverse.  I call this the [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121).  Here is serves an important role of localizing the Symbol `op`.  You could also use `HoldPattern[op] -> . . .` to do the same.

Here is another option:

```
Function[op, HoldForm[op@##] & @@ RandomInteger[{1, 15}, 2]] /@ 
  RandomChoice[{Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide}, 10]
```

[image]