# How to evaluate some parts of an expression inside Hold?

Tags: evaluation, hold

I want to return a `Hold` expression but with some parts pre-evaluated. The easiest way to explain this is probably through code example. Here is what I have currently:

```
In[1]  := y = 3;

In[2]  := Hold[f[x, y]]
Out[2] := Hold[f[x, y]]

In[3]  := Hold[f[x, Evaluate[y]]]
Out[3] := Hold[f[x, Evaluate[y]]]
```

But I want something which returns `Hold[f[x, 3]]`. (My actual use case is to return a `Hold` expression involving the value of symbols which are local to a `Block`.)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Actually it might not be a duplicate, depending on what is your starting expression.  You might do `With[{y=1+1}, Hold[{x,y}]]`, which will first evaluate `1+1` then inject the result in a held expression.

Comment: Recommendation: `Hold[f[x, y]] /. HoldPattern[y] :> RuleCondition[y]`  -- and I think this should be closed as a duplicate of the question linked above.

Comment: If the items to replace are always complete Symbols you could use `With` as Szabolcs showed, or: `Function[y, Hold[f[x, y]]][y]`

Comment: I came up with `Function[y, Hold[f[x, y]]][y]` pretty much immediately after I posted the question. But anyway I think Szabolc's `With` solution is slightly cleaner. Yes, the thing to replace is always a `Symbol`, so it's not an exact duplicate of pattern replacement problem.

Comment: Since the thing to replace is always a Symbol I propose "reverse" replacement like this:  `y /. y_ :> Hold[f[x, y]]`  see: [(1929)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/121) for examples.  Would you object to having this question closed as "already answered" via a combination of [(29317)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/121) and that?

Answer (score 3):

In version 10 have you looked at `Inactivate` and `Activate`?

```
(* ClearAll["Global`*"] *)
f[x_, y_] := x + y
expr = Inactivate[f[x, y]];
```

Now have a look at `expr` and see that `f` is inactivated.  You can also activate `f` to see the result of the operation.

```
expr
Activate[expr]
```

Now set `y` and look at `expr`, then activate it.

```
y = 3;
expr
Activate[expr]
```

I hope this has helped.