# Evaluate within Hold

Tags: display, hold

When I do...

```
p=3;
HoldForm[Evaluate[p]-2]
```

I get:

```
Evaluate[p]-2
```

BUT I'd like to get:

```
3-2
```

How can I get this result? I want to display the subtraction, unevaluated -- but I want an expression *within* the subtraction to get evaluated.

Comment: Why not `With[]`? `With[{p = 3}, HoldForm[p - 2]]`

Comment: @J.M. Yes that is better. Why not add a separate answer?

Comment: Because that bit is also in the thread you linked to, and the threads that thread is linked to.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way:

```
HoldForm[p - 2] /. HoldPattern[p] :> RuleCondition[p]
```

Comment: Found after some deeper digging into comments of this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75260/how-to-evaluate-some-parts-of-an-expression-inside-hold

Comment: Sean, perhaps you could add the `With` method outlined by J.M. in your answer, since you found it useful as well. (+1 for self-answering!)