# How can I use sequence in plotting domain?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, sequence

I would like to plot a function but have a domain defined elsewhere as follows:

```
xrange = Sequence[0, 2π];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, xrange}]
```

However, this doesn't work resulting in the error `Range specification {x, xrange} is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}.` I've tried to put an [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) around `{x, xrange}` but Mathematica was not impressed.

I can think of two easy workarounds:

```
xrange = {0, 2π};
Plot[Sin[x], {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}]
Plot[Sin[x], Evaluate[{x, ##} & @@ xrange]]
```

While these are fine solutions, they involve changing xrange to a `List` in a place where [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) seems to fit perfectly. Is there a [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) solution that I can use?

Comment: closely related: [1929](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/5478)

Comment: Cleaner: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, ##}] & @@ {0, 2 π}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be also nice to preserve scoping of `x` by `Plot` so:

```
xrange = Sequence[0, 2 \[Pi]];
x = 1;
Plot[Sin[x], {x, ##}] &[xrange]
```

[image]

or, based on linked topic:

```
{xrange} /. {r__} :> Plot[Sin[x], {x, r}]
```

Comment: Ah, now I understand. If `x` is define somewhere then @m0nhawk's solution fails?

Comment: @JeffDror Yes, unfortnately. `Evaluate` prevents `x` from being properly scoped.

Comment: What if you use `With[]` for the insertion?

Comment: @J. M. `Sequence` head will be there and `Plot` will still think it is only one argument. Something like in the linked topic.

Comment: Ooh, forgot that thread. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 4):

And what *Mathematica* version you have?

This works for me in *Mathematica* 10.0.2:

```
xrange = Sequence[0, 2 \[Pi]];
Plot[Sin[x], Evaluate@{x, xrange}]
```

Comment: Hmm, this actually does seem to work now (Mathematica 10.0.0 Linux) . I was sure that I tried this... Thanks for your response.

Comment: @JeffDror `xrange = Sequence[0, 2 \[Pi]];    x = 1;
Plot[Sin[x], Evaluate@{x, xrange}]`