# Overriding the behavior of Dot

Tags: replacement, options

I would like to override the behavior of [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html), so that `Dot[u,v]` will return a scalar instead of a 1x1 matrix in the case that the result is 1x1. The behavior I want is given by [`CircleDot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircleDot.html) defined below.

```
CircleDot[u_, v_] := u.v /. {{{a_}} -> a};
```

I have tried experimenting with [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html) and I have studied [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937).  Any help you could provide would be most welcome.

As an example, consider

```
{{1,2,3}}.Transpose[{{1,2,3}}]
```

The result is {{14}}. Whereas

```
CircleDot[{{1,2,3}},Transpose[{{1,2,3}]]
```

Gives 14

I want to work with row and column vectors i.e. 1xn and nx1 matrices.

Comment: I'm confused. If I do `Dot[{1}, {2}]`, MMA returns `2`.

Comment: `Unprotect[Dot]` redefine `Dot` `Protect[Dot]`? Please provide an example of the vectors.

Comment: I have to think a simple example would help clarify this question.

Comment: John, if I write your example as `Dot[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]`, it works fine, and the result is already `14`. "Because of the way the Wolfram Language uses lists to represent vectors and matrices, you never have to distinguish between "row" and "column" vectors." ([link to docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VectorsAndMatrices.html)). Wouldn't that be acceptable in your case?

Comment: I understand that Mathematica treats lists a vectors.  I want to work with standard notation using row and column vectors for in-class examples.

Comment: @John I see. You might want to specify that explicitly in your question then.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do the `Unprotect` thing, take care to restrict your mod to the specific case:

```
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[a_List, b_List] /; 
    Dimensions[a][[1]] == 1 &&
       Dimensions[a] == Reverse@Dimensions[b] :=
         Total@Thread@Times[First@a, First/@b]
Protect[Dot];
x = {{1, 2, 3}};
y = {{4}, {5}, {6}};
Row[ { MatrixForm[x] MatrixForm[y], " = " , x.y}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this approach will work for me.