# How to get LogPlot to accept a Sequence for its Min/Max Limits

Tags: plotting, sequence

If you use `Plot` like this,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 5}]
```

it produces the correct `Sin` graph with x from 1 to 5. Something that also works is to give the xmin and xmax values as a sequence like this,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, Sequence[1, 5]}]
```

However when I try to do the same thing for `LogPlot` (or indeed `LogLinearPlot` or `LogLogPlot`),

```
LogPlot[Sin[x], {x, Sequence[1, 5]}]
```

it outputs this (I don't believe this is even an error message):

```
Graphics`LogPlotDump`scaledPlot[]
```

How do you get `LogPlot` to accept a sequence for its limits?

Comment: closely related: [Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/5478)

Comment: Can you describe what is the use case? I mean, I suppose you are not typing "Sequence" by hand, \right?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2):

The same way it should be done for regular plot:

```
LogPlot[Sin[x], {x, Sequence[1, 5]} // Evaluate]
```

Or if `x` has potentially been defined as a global value elsewhere

```
Block[{x}, LogPlot[Sin[x], {x, Sequence[1, 5]} // Evaluate]]
```

[image]