# Function of a function, both of a list of variables

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, evaluation, sequence

I am trying to avoid dealing with long explicit lists of variables.

What i do so far is the following:

```
VarList={x_, y_};
ParList={x, y};
ValList={2, 3};
```

What works

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + 3 y^3;
g[x_, y_] := 3 f[x, y];

f@@ValList
g@@ValList

Out[1]=85
Out[2]=255
```

Now what i would like to do but it does not work:

```
Clear[f, g];

f[Sequence@@VarList] := x^2 + 3 y^3;
g[Sequence@@VarList] := 3 f@@ParList;

f@@ValList
g@@ValList

Out[3]=85
Out[4]=3 (x^2 + 3 y^3)
```

How can I achieve numerical evaluation of `g` in the last step?

**Edit:**

Regarding the first solution by @kglr: The solution works as given but there are subtle issues that i want to describe here.

The suggestion is:

```
g[Sequence @@ VarList] := Evaluate[3 f @@ ParList];
g @@ ValList
```

> 255

This works. However,

```
g[Sequence @@ VarList] := 3 Evaluate[ f @@ ParList];
g @@ ValList
```

> 3 (x^2 + 3 y^3)

Does not. Also, it does not seem to work for more complicated constructs. Concretely i wanted to use something along

```
g[Sequence @@ VarList] := Evaluate[ArrayFlatten[{{SparseArray[{{f @@ ParList}}]}}]];
g @@ ValList //MatrixForm
```

> (x^2+3 y^3)

Does not work. To finally make my confusion complete, note that the last expression works again, if i drop both of the outer pair of curly brackets. That is

```
g[Sequence @@ VarList] := Evaluate[ArrayFlatten[SparseArray[{{f @@ ParList}}]]];
g @@ ValList //MatrixForm
```

> (85)

works again. Do you undestand this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because Mathematica functions are really pattern-matching, it's possible to simplify the function definition by making `f` and `g` take a list of parameters as input:

```
VarList={x_, y_};
ParList={x, y};
ValList={2, 3};

f[VarList] := x^2 + 3 y^3;
g[VarList] := Evaluate[3 f@ParList]

Print@ f[ValList]
Print@ g[ValList]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8sscgns7jEtroiXkehMr7WmisALgIUAPLDEnMgfCMdBWMgnystGqopVsHKVqEizkhBW8FYoTLO2JorHUXKtSwxpzSxJDXaWCHNAWpsLBdXQFFmXomDAsiYHIgQVCQdLvL/PwA)

That way you use `f[{2, 3}]` or `f@{2, 3}` to call it.

2. [`Pattern` (`:`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) can be used:

```
VarList=ParList:{x_,y_};
ValList={2, 3};

f[VarList] := x^2 + 3 y^3;
g[VarList] := 3 f@ParList

Print@ f[ValList]
Print@ g[ValList]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8sscgns7jENgBCW1VXxOtUxtdac4Ul5oAlqo10FIyBfK60aKjaWAUrW4WKOCMFbQVjhco4Y2uudBQpY4U0B6hxXFwBRZl5JQ4KIM1g82JhIulwkf//AQ)

Explanation: The definition of `f` and `g` expands to

```
f[ParList:{x_,y_}] := x^2 + 3 y^3;
g[ParList:{x_,y_}] := 3 f@ParList
```

This also makes `Evaluate` unnecessary. It may be undesirable to use `Evaluate`, for example:

```
ParList={x};

f[ParList:{x_}] := Simplify@x;
g[{x_}] := Evaluate[f@ParList];

Print@ f@{a*b+a*c+a*d+a*e}
Print@ g@{a*b+a*c+a*d+a*e}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8gscgns7jEtrqi1pqLKy0ayreqroivjVWwslUIzswtyMlMq3SosOZKj4YLu5Yl5pQmlqRGpzlAtcQC9QcUZeaVOCikOVQnaiVpJ2olA3EKEKfWwqTSMaX@/wcA)

Comment: I find that this solution is superior to the others because it spares the `Evaluate` and i really only want to evaluate the code in the very last step for reasons of runtime. Nevertheless, before i accept the answer let me ask one thing: After implementing your solution my code takes roughly ~3 times as much time as before, which is undesirable. The evaluate is gone, so what takes extra time here? Isn't there a way to make it run as fast as before. I mean in the end all what i ask for is just a nicer optical appearance of my code without lengthy list of parameters everywhere. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry this was my mistake, your code works just fine, without any loss of speed! (I had overlooked some instances of `Evaluate` which were in place after i tried to implement the solution of @kglr above.). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer user202729's alternative using [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) but adhering to your original specification your goal can be achieved with a method from [Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/121):

```
VarList = {x_, y_};
ParList = {x, y};
ValList = {2, 3};

{VarList, ParList} /. {{var__}, {par__}} :> 
  (
   f[var] := x^2 + 3 y^3;
   g[var] := 3 f[par];
  )

g @@ ValList
```

> ```
> 255
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't do this.
2. `g[Sequence @@ VarList] = 3 f @@ ParList;`