# Prevent argument substitution in held expression when injecting into unevaluated code

Tags: evaluation, replacement, expression-manipulation, hold

I want to write a custom `sow/reap` pair to wrap any piece of code in `sow[code]` and call `reap` to collect the timing of `code` with a tag that is the *completely* unevaluated version of `code`. My proble is that I cannot effectively withhold argument value substitution. I expect to use this pair only on my own functions `fun` so I can freely get and set `DownValues` as I like. Of course I expect to put many `sow` in my definition of `fun`. See example:

```
ClearAll[sow, reap, fun];

Attributes[reap] = {HoldAllComplete};
reap[x_] := Module[{h = (Hold@x)[[1, 0]], old, new, res},
   old = DownValues[Evaluate@h]; (* store old DownValues *)
   new = old /. {sow[y_] :> 
       Block[{time, out}, {time, out} = AbsoluteTiming@y; 
        Sow[ToString@Unevaluated@y -> time]; out]};
   DownValues[Evaluate@h] = new;(* install new DownValues *)
   res = Reap@x;
   DownValues[Evaluate@h] = old;(* restore old DownValues *)
   res];

fun[i_Integer] := sow@(Print["CALLED"]; Table[None, {i}]);
```

Now call `reap` on `fun`:

```
In[1]:= reap[fun[2]]

During evaluation of In[1]:= CALLED

Out[1]= {{None, None}, {{"Print[CALLED]; Table[None, {2}]" -> 0.0000418147}}}
```

This is almost what I want, but not exactly. **How can I keep `i` from evaluating to the argument value `2`?** That is, I want to have `"Print[CALLED]; Table[None, {i}]"` instead of `"Print[CALLED]; Table[None, {2}]"` in the resulting tag. I guess this cannot be solved locally within any definition of `sow`, hence the `DownValue`-manipulation within `reap`. Can it be solved with the [injector pattern](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/89) or the [Trott-Strzebonski](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29318/89) in-place evaluation?

I know that I can specify tags manually in `Sow` but I specifically want to avoid this and simply use `sow` as a one-argument function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stringify or otherwise protect the argument of `sow` outside of the usual down-value application (when the down-value is evaluated, the substitution is already made as you've noticed). This can easily be done using the Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation mentioned in the question:

```
ClearAll[sow, reap, fun];

Attributes[reap] = {HoldAllComplete};
reap[x_] := Module[{h = (Hold@x)[[1, 0]], old, new, res},
   old = DownValues[Evaluate@h]; (* store old DownValues *)
   new = old /. sow[y_] :> 
    With[
     {tag=ToString@Unevaluated@y},
       Module[{time, out}, 
        {time, out} = AbsoluteTiming@y; 
        Sow[tag -> time];
        out
       ]/;True
    ];
   DownValues[Evaluate@h] = new;(* install new DownValues *)
   res = Reap@x;
   DownValues[Evaluate@h] = old;(* restore old DownValues *)
   res];

fun[i_Integer] := sow@(Print["CALLED"]; Table[None, {i}]);
```

Notice the use of `Module` instead of `Block` (as suggested by @WReach in the comments): This prevents the local `time` and `out` variables from colliding with like-named variables used inside the argument of `sow`, which would otherwise give strange results. Generally, it is better to always use `Module`, unless you have a very specific reason that you need `Block`.

Now, the functions work as intended:

```
reap[fun[2]]

During evaluation of CALLED
(* {{None, None}, {{"Print[CALLED]; Table[None, {i}]" -> 0.000075}}} *)
```

Comment: +1.  In addition, I would advise the OP to replace `Block` with `Module` in the `new` definition.  Otherwise, unexpected results could occur should any expression in the evaluation chain for `y` happen to use the symbols `time` or `out`.

Comment: @WReach Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the code & added a note. (I did think of it at one point, but for some strange reason I decided that it wasn't an issue here - so thanks again for catching that :) )

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was the missing piece. Actually, I think I've built a pretty good profiler based on this.