# How to replace expressions in a `HoldComplete` and then evaluate them?

Tags: evaluation, replacement, hold

Example:

```
HoldComplete[{b,a,a,a}] /. a->Nothing
HoldComplete[{b,a,a,a}] /. l_List->DeleteCases[l,a]
HoldComplete[{b,a,a,a}] /. l_List:>DeleteCases[l,a]
HoldComplete[{b,a,b,a}] //. {head___,a..,tail___}->{head,tail}
```

Only the last works but it's has a low efficiency. What's the right way to do things like this?

Comment: may be this could be of help [injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937)

Comment: And for this specific example: `HoldComplete[{b, a, a, a}] // DeleteCases[#, a, \[Infinity]] &`