# How to multi-Set a group of lists?

Tags: sets

I have a group of lists, for example:

```
lists = RandomInteger[10, {100, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{6, 7}, {7, 4}, {3, 3}, ....}
> ```

Now, I want to multi-set as follow:

```
ls1={6,7};
ls2={7,4};
,,,,
lsX=lists[[X]]
```

How to do that by a simple way?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

How about `lsX` but not `ls[X]`?

I have tried to generate a list of names:

```
names=ToExpression["ls" <> ToString@# & /@ Range[100]]
```

How to multi set then?

Comment: All methods below are fine but fail as soon as you evaluate them twice. See [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lists = RandomInteger[10, {100, 2}];       
Table[ls[i] = lists[[i]], {i, 1, Length @ lists}];
```

OR

```
Do[ls[i] = lists[[i]], {i, 1, Length @ lists}];
```

OR

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length @ lists, i++, ls[i] = lists[[i]]]
```

Now you can individually get their values e.g `ls[1]`, `ls[2]` etc.

**EDIT**

If you really want `ls1, ls2 ...` then the following should do it:

```
Table[Evaluate[Symbol["ls" <> ToString[i]]] = lists[[i]], {i, 1, Length @ lists}];
```

Now you can use `ls1` , `ls2`, etc

Comment: How about lsX but not ls[X]?

Comment: @bushiwo. You're better off doing it this way in *Mathematica*. Unless there's a specific reason you want it that way.

Comment: @bushiwo. See my edit. That's what you want right?

Comment: Could you tell me why I can't use my names function in my UPDATE?

Comment: @bushiwo. All you've done is create a bunch of *Mathematica* expressions (in this case symbols) using `ToExpression`. Now you have to assign them values individually, which defeats the purpose. In my updated answer, I create and assign the values at once. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @bushiwo Just as an aside note, Runny was in the right path not using `ls1` but `ls[1]`, much more easier to manage in Mathematica. If you _really, really_ need different names, the edited answer (or mine) gives you that, but beware! you are probably in the wrong path

Comment: Thx~ I know that ls[1] is more easier to manage in Mathematica, I just want to have a try.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I think this particularly useful, but it does exactly what you asked for:

```
lists = RandomInteger[10, {5, 2}]; 

MapIndexed[(Evaluate[Symbol["ls" <> ToString[#2[[1]]]]] = #1) &, lists];

{ls1, ls2, ls3, ls4, ls5} == lists
(*
True
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will achieve your aim. I have used "l" rather than "ls" but you can change.

```
MapThread[
 Set[#1, #2] &, {Symbol /@ (Table["l" <> ToString[j], {j, 100}]), 
  lists}]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
Set @@@ Transpose[{names, lists}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable application of `Map`, which uses the shortcut `/@`

```
lists = RandomInteger[10, {100, 2}]; 
(ls[#] = lists[[#]]) & /@ Range[Length[lists]]
```

As requested, `ls[1]` is the first of the elements in list, `ls[2]` the second, etc. As suggested by Belisarius, this can also be done more succinctly using `MapIndexed`

```
MapIndexed[(all[#2[[1]]] = #1) &, lists]
```

Comment: I was referring to `MapIndexed[(all[#2[[1]]] = #1) &, lists]`

Comment: Very nice. I guess this means that I was reinventing `MapIndexed` -- don't think I've ever used it before.