# Evaluating a String that is a Variable

Tags: evaluation, string-manipulation

I have a Variable assigned a value, say

> ImportantDocuments=1

How do I make

> N["ImportantDocuments"]

evaluate to be

> 1

instead of

> ImportantDocuments

I found that

> N[ToExpression["ImportantDocuments"]]

gives the correct answer.

Comment: To be pedantic, it is not possible to do that, since `N[...]` will give you `1.`, not `1` :D Jokes aside, to answer your question, look up `Symbol` and `ToExpression`.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5

Comment: thanks, that duplicate is correct and helpful

Comment: You're welcome :)