# How can I use an InputField value as a variable name to save to?

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, gui-construction, variable

I'm trying to save some settings and results from `Manipulate`, and I want to be able to save them to different variable names. The code I have is something like

```
Manipulate[x,
 {{x, x1, "value"}, ControlType -> InputField},
 {{variablename, defaultname, "variable name"}, ControlType -> InputField},
 Button["save", variablename = x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, the functionality I want is that I can write a variable name into the second `InputField`, hit save, and have the value of `x` assigned to a variable of that name.

However as it stands, hitting save only updates the value of the `variablename` variable within `Manipulate`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to actually write to a named file on disk. You just want to assign a value to a variable whose name is a variable itself. Is this interpretation of your question correct?

Comment: yes! that's it.

Comment: question now updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Provide name as a `String` and use one of those methods to assign the value:
[How do you programatically load data into symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

```
Manipulate[x,
 {{variablename, "test", "variable name"}, (InputField[#, String] &)}, 
 {{x, x1, "value"}, ControlType -> InputField}, 
 Button["save", 
  ToExpression[variablename, StandardForm, Function[name, name = x, HoldFirst]
  ]
 ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work so long as you don't try to assign a variable that already has an assignment

```
Manipulate[x, 
  {{variablename, defaultname, "variable name"}, ControlType -> InputField}, 
  {{x, x1, "value"}, ControlType -> InputField}, 
  Button["save", Evaluate[variablename] = x]]
```

Comment: To remove that constraint is pretty difficult, by the way.