# How to define a function returning x -> 2 while x = 1?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, replacement, rule

What I want is an `f` that will work like this:

```
x = 1;
myOut = f[x];    (* it should return {x -> 2} , the 2 is the new data *)
x /.myOut        (* execute this line if I want to overwrite the current x;
                    or I can leave my old x as is but still have the new data
                    in myOut  *)
```

The main challenge for me now is to:

print the rule to a variable, while this variable is already assigned a value, say, `x = 1`.

In the module I have to avoid using its name `x` because it will **automatically** get substituted by 1 (in this example above). The variable name should be provided by the user so that its name is unknown and I cannot hard-code it in my module.

So far, I can fetch the input variable name `x` no problem. I can also overwrite `x` inside the module without explicitly using its name. I'm stuck at printing it in a rule.

Using `HoldForm[ ]` creates a tiny white space that ruins the rule (while avoiding being detected as **not a rule** when executed!), and neither does `Defer[ ]` work in a mysterious way (to me).

Below is this failed attempt with the tiny white space:

```
myFunc[inVar_] := Module[{newData,},

   newData = 1 + inVar; (* just some computation *)

   Print[ HoldForm[ inVar ] -> newData ];
    (* Besides Print[ ], I also tried Return[], List[], or just the rule (expression) itself; the outcome are all the same *)

   ];  (* End of Module *)
```

For example, `myOut = myFunc[x]` will print `x->2` with a tiny white space right after the `x` and before the arrow. It kind of looks like `x,->2` where the comma represents the white space.

The usual `x/.myOut` will not work because of this. I've tried it, if I manually remove that tiny space then the rule will work.

Besides `HoldForm[ ]`, using a string for the variable name creates double quotes.
`Inactive[ ]`, `Unevaluated[ ]`, `With[ ]` don't work either, at least the ways I've tried.

I'm currently working on `MakeExpressions[ ]` and boxes, but I haven't made much progress and am wondering if I'm on the right track.

Thank you very much.

-------- a little info hopefully for more efficient discussions ----

Thanks to the many answers to other questions provided by Kuba, Mr.Wizard and Leonid, just to name a few, I have learned how to:

(a) obtain the variable name provided by the user and append sequential index or strings etc to make use of it,

(b) inject stuff into held expressions, one of the coolest thing I've ever seen with `/._[x__] ->`

(c) forcefully assign values to existing variables without explicitly using its name, [like so](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/784/40096).

As a whole I consider myself a beginner, knowing basic syntax and some isolated tricks only.

Comment: can you give an example what kind of output you are expecting from what kind of input.

Comment: myOut = myModule[ var, blah ], either this or without the assignment to myOut, I'd like the output to be % = {var -> some nested list } such that I can choose to update or not with this:    var /. %

Comment: The point is that the rule ties the variable name with the output, instead of  the data being just some lists themselves and not obvious which list goes to which variable. At the same time, printing the variable names with strings causes extra work in accessing the outcome.

Comment: how about `x/.x->f[x]`. You don't need any module for that.

Comment: `f[x0_] := HoldPattern[x] -> 2`?  You can't simply have `x -> 2` if `x` has been assigned a value (e.g., `x = 1`).  Or possibly `ClearAll[f]; SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]; f[var_] := Module[{newData}, <code to calculate newData >; HoldPattern[var] -> newData]`.

Comment: oh, I wasn't familiar with HoldPattern[ ] and I'm glad to learn this useful tool. Thanks. However, your suggestion doesn't work for my situation....it's all my bad..... after trying your construct, I just found out that my original intent is ill-posed. The built-in functions of Mathematica CANNOT print rules when the variable is already assigned a value. I have been misled by my own stupidity from the very beginning. Ha, so I guess in this sense you helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to achieve exactly the same thing you want, because `ReplaceAll` and `Rule` don't have `Hold*` attributes i.e. both of them automatically evaluate their arguments. Just observe the output of the following code piece:

```
x = 1;
x + 1 /. x -> 2 // Trace
(* {{{x, 1}, 1 + 1, 2}, 
   {{x, 1}, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2}, 
   2 /. 1 -> 2, 2} *)
```

Before `ReplaceAll` begins to work, `x + 1` will evaluate first and become `2`, then `x` in the left hand side of `Rule` will evaluate to `1`, finally `x + 1 /. x -> 2` actually becomes `2 /. 1 -> 2`, which certainly won't output `3` because pattern matching is syntactic matching rather than semantic matching. (If you feel confused, read [this](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v7i3/features/harris/). )

However, something very similar can be achieved, we just need to introduce a help function and adjust the evaluation order a little, like this:

```
SetAttributes[rep, HoldFirst]
Attributes[adjust] = HoldFirst
SetAttributes[myFunc, HoldAll]

adjust[a_ /. b_] := Unevaluated@a /. b
rep[a_, b_] := Unevaluated@a /. b

myFunc[inVar_] := Module[{newData}, newData = 1 + inVar; HoldPattern[inVar] -> newData]

x = 1;

myOut = myFunc[x]
(* HoldPattern[x] -> 2 *)

(* Solution 1 *)
(x + a + 100)~rep~myOut
(* 102 + a *)

(* Solution 2 *)
(x + a + 100) /. myOut // adjust
(* 102 + a *)
```

Comment: oh, another delayed function, interesting!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I still understand your question properly. I will delete it later if it is completely irrelevant.

Let there be a function

```
tab[x_] := # x & /@ Range[5]
```

which gives an list for a variable

```
tab[g]
```

> {g, 2 g, 3 g, 4 g, 5 g}

Now I define a new function

```
lin[f__] := Variables[f][[1]] -> f
```

Which gives you the result as rule

```
lin[tab[x]]
```

> x -> {x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x, 5 x}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think it's very relevant! Although it doesn't really solve my problem, it's another good trick to get the variable's name. My bad, I need to revise my original post.

Comment: Taking your code, if x is already assigned, say x = 1, then Variables[ ] will not be able to get the symbol.

Comment: I would like to have a robust module that prints the variable name as a symbol in a rule, just like Solve[  lhs == rhs, x ] will give you x -> sol regardless of there being a global x = 1 or not.

Comment: We can either copy or paste the output from Solve[ ], or use % or Out[ ] to directly apply the rule to an expression. If after fetching the variable name I print it as a string, then even though as the OutputForm the quotes are invisible, it's actually "x" -> sol , and this rule doesn't apply to the variable x.