# Assigning ::usage in a package for in Private generated symbols?

Tags: packages, usage-messages

I'm having difficulties assigning `::usage` in a *Mathematica* package for symbols in a list or dataset, that will only be defined later in a `` `Private` `` subcontext.

In `` `Private` `` I have something like this:

```
list = Dataset[
  {<|"name" -> "Alpha", "age" -> 123|>, 
   <|"name" -> "Beta", "age" -> 456|>, 
   <|"name" -> "Gamma", "age" -> 789|>
}];

Do[Evaluate[Symbol["my" <> list[i, "name"]]] = list[i, "age"], {i, 1, Length[list]}];
```

How can I now generically specify a `::usage` for the symbols `myAlpha`, etc. before they are even generated? I would like to, as usual, do something like this right after `BeginPackage[]`

```
Do[Evaluate[Symbol["my" <> list[i, "name"]]]::usage = "", {i, 1, Length[list]}];
```

but now obviously list is not yet defined. Can I somehow set this delayed or on hold or anything until the dataset was generated? I couldn't get it working so far.

Thanks alot,

T

Comment: Will `list` be created before you start defining any of `my*` symbols? In which context should they be created?

Comment: If you need to create the symbols in a specific context, prepend that context to their name (I mean the string in `Symbol`).

Comment: @Kuba Yes, `list` is created before the `my*` symbols, just as stated in my question. I'd like them all to be in context Private, but use `::usage` to be able to auto-complete the `my*` symbols with their correctly assigned values (`"age"` in this case).

Comment: I'm assuming autocomplete in a notebook. So they are not private, they are meant to be ``Package` ``. Then, as Szabolcs suggested use ``"MyPackage`my"<>``.

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I still can't get it to work though, maybe also because I'm new to writing packages. My problem is, I think, that when I use `::usage` right after the beginning of my package, it is referring to Symbols that will only be defined later in `Private`. In addition to my initial comment, here a complete example package. What I would like to do is to get the my* `Symbols` into autocomplete in notebooks, and this generically and not listing one by one by hand with a `::usage`. In the example below, list is obviously not assigned to anything yet, when I want to use `::usage`:

Comment: BeginPackage["test`"];
Do[Evaluate[Symbol["my"<>list[i,"name"]]]::usage="",{i,1,Length[list]}];
Begin["`Private`"];
list=Dataset[{<|"name"->"Alpha","age"->123|>,<|"name"->"Beta","age"->456|>,<|"name"->"Gamma","age"->789|>}];
Do[Evaluate[Symbol["my"<>#[i,"name"]]]=#[i,"age"],{i,1,Length[#]}]&@list;
End[]; (* `Private` *)
EndPackage[];

Comment: Any thoughts on this, @Kuba ?

Comment: @T_202 so, what about that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

I've changed your `Evaluate[Symbol["my" <> list[i, "name"]]] =...` to something more flexible. Read more in: [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];


Begin["`Private`"];


list = {<|"name" -> "Alpha", "age" -> 123|>, <|"name" -> "Beta", 
    "age" -> 456|>, <|"name" -> "Gamma", "age" -> 789|>};

ToExpression[
  "Test`my" <> #name, StandardForm, Function[name, name = #age, HoldFirst]
] & /@ list;


ToExpression[
  "my" <> #name, StandardForm, Function[name, name::usage = "test", HoldFirst]
] & /@ list; 
  (*notice that the second time they are mentioned they will be found on $ContextPath*)




privateSymbol = {myAlpha, myGamma};

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

[image]

I've dropped `Dataset` till this problem is solved: [Problems with Dataset's querying on a fresh Kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126010/5478)

Comment: Thanks alot @Kuba, that helps and also thanks for pointing out the bug with the Datasets! With respect to this, hopefully this also helped others.