# Extract sublists automatically and name them

Tags: list-manipulation, symbols

I have these 6 random walks of size 100 generated into a list:

```
x = Table[
   Flatten@NestList[0.1 + # + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1] &,0, 99], 
   6
]
```

Now I'd like to extract each random walk (each row) from this matrix and automatically name them `x1, x2 , ... , x6`.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: closely related: [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

Comment: `var = Table[Unique["x"], 6];var = x` can help?

Comment: `MapIndexed[
 Set[Evaluate[Symbol["x" <> IntegerString[First@#2]]], #1] &, x]`

Comment: So the question is fine, but why do you want to do this, rather than just using `x[[1]]`, `x[[2]]`, etc.? It just seems to clutter the name-space without much gain. In fact, you *lose* something by not being able to operate on all of the lists at the same time (by using `Table` or `Map` or ...).

Comment: Well in this particular application, you're right, it would be better to just use Part[], but in some cases, I need to import several variables at once, so naming them is more practical then having to remember their "id".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct method would be as follows:

```
{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6} = 
  Table[Flatten@NestList[0.1 + # + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1] &,
     0, 99], 6]
```

To automate this process for longer tables, you can use this function to do the same thing:

```
setRows[s_String, m_List] := 
  With[{vars = s <> # & /@ IntegerString@Range@Length@m}, 
    Clear @@ vars; Evaluate[Symbol /@ vars] = m;]
```

For example, executing setRows["x",matrix], would create variables x1, x2, x3,... each containing the corresponding row of matrix.

To name them in any other fashion, say var1, var2,..., use setRows["var",matrix].

Comment: Symbol instead of ToExpression would be the perfect function here.

Comment: Thanks! I'll fix it now. I'm working on a solution that doesn't return errors if the variables already have ownvalues

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Updated to overwrite previous values of variables, if any, and to name the variables in any manner.