# How do I plot multiple lists that were assigned variables created in an iterative fashion from a larger matrix?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a 70x16 array of values ("DATA22K") imported from a .xls spreadsheet, with the x-values (time) being column 1, and the fluorescence intensities of 15 samples (over time) being columns 2 thru 16.

I wanted to create lists in an iterative fashion to easily plot and analyze the samples. I have written two approaches, assigning variables such that each list variable corresponded to the trial number for each sample. The approaches are:

1) `Do[Evaluate[Symbol["Tr22K" <> ToString[i]]] == Transpose[{Time22K, FRAP22K[[All, i]]}], {i, 1, 15}];`

in which I've used simple variable assignment and `span` to separate the time column ("Time22K") from the sample data ("FRAP22K"), and:

2) `Table[Evaluate[Symbol["Fr22K" <> ToString[i]]] == 
   Transpose[{DATA22K[[All, 1]], DATA22K[[All, i]]}], {i, 2, 15, 1}];`

Both approaches create the lists (though approach #2 returns a list of "false" values when clicking ""show output"), but when I run `ListLinePlot[Tr22Ki]`, neither approach produces a graph-- I have to plot each list created individually.

How can I perform functions and commands on all the lists produced (not just plot)?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Change `==` to `=`? (see [Equal](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html) vs [Set](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html) in the docs)

Comment: This make your lists `lists=Table[Transpose[{DATA22K[[All, 1]], DATA22K[[All, i]]}], {i, 2, 15, 
  1}];` and after to apply a function say, `ListPlot`, you can do `Map[ListPlot,lists]`

Comment: This works, but I would like to store the values for each plot with a variable name, such that I can reference the lists individually later. Is there a way I can do so with this format?

Ultimately, I will be analytically extracting certain parameters from the datasets via curve-fitting.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478